# Get the last day of the month

Tags: python, date

Is there a way using Python's standard library to easily determine (i.e. one function call) the last day of a given month?

If the standard library doesn't support that, does the dateutil package support this?

Answer (score 1479, accepted):

[`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) provides this information:

> calendar.**monthrange**(year, month)
>     Returns weekday of first day of the month and number of days in month, for the specified *year* and *month*.

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(2002, 1)
(1, 31)
>>> calendar.monthrange(2008, 2)  # leap years are handled correctly
(4, 29)
>>> calendar.monthrange(2100, 2)  # years divisible by 100 but not 400 aren't leap years
(0, 28)
```

so:

```
calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
```

seems like the simplest way to go.

Comment: I can't be the only one thinking `monthrange` is a confusing name. You would think it would return `(first_day, last_day)`, not `(week_day_of_first_day, number_of_days)`

Comment: first_day wouldn't be especially useful since it would always be 1. But I agree, week_day_of_first_day seems unrelated to "month range".

Comment: For those who didn't know: calendar is in the standard library.

Comment: knowing the day of the week of the first day does allow you to calculate how many weekdays are in the month using only basic arithmetic

Answer (score 281):

If you don't want to import the `calendar` module, a simple two-step function can also be:

```py
import datetime

def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    # The day 28 exists in every month. 4 days later, it's always next month
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    # subtracting the number of the current day brings us back one month
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)
```

Outputs:

```bash
>>> for month in range(1, 13):
...     print(last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2022, month, 1)))
...
2022-01-31
2022-02-28
2022-03-31
2022-04-30
2022-05-31
2022-06-30
2022-07-31
2022-08-31
2022-09-30
2022-10-31
2022-11-30
2022-12-31
```

Comment: @VikramsinhGaikwad - just use datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)

Comment: `datetime` doesn't work for years [after 9999](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.MAXYEAR), whereas `calendar.monthrange` does.

Comment: @Boris That hardly seems a problem with the answer, but Python itself. Also, now I'm dead curious as to what you are working on.

Comment: It's not a problem, just a caveat I thought someone else might find useful in the future. I'm not working on anything but I've heard this is a problem for people calculating nuclear waste storage and astronomy.

Comment: There's nothing special about the 28th. You can as well add 31 days to the first of the current month, then step backwards in the same manner. Since you might need the first in the same calculation, this saves a step.

Comment: Yeah, something like `(any_day.replace(day=28) + timedelta(days=4)).replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=-1)`

Comment: Why wouldn't someone want to import `calendar`? It's in the standard library.

Answer (score 125):

EDIT: See @Blair Conrad's answer for a cleaner solution

---

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2000, 2, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.date(2000, 1, 31)
```

Comment: I would actually call this cleaner, except for the fact that it fails in December when `today.month + 1 == 13` and you get a `ValueError`.

Comment: You can solve that by using `(today.month % 12) + 1` since `12 % 12` gives 0

Comment: Some weird daylight saving switch on a 31st of a month (I think that doesn't exist today, but the future might be different) might render the 31st of that month with a length of just 23 hours, so that subtracting one day lets you end at 23:00:00 on the 30th.  That's a freak case, sure, but it shows that the approach isn't sound.

Comment: I liked the `today.month % 12` idea but it doesn't work when you are trying to get the last day of december because it will go to the previous year. Here is a one liner to do it.

`datetime.date(year + int(month / 12), (month % 12) + 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)`

Answer (score 121):

This is actually pretty easy with [`dateutil.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html). `day=31` will always always return the last day of the month:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date_in_feb = datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 21)
print(datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 21) + relativedelta(day=31))  # End-of-month
# datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 0, 0)
```

Install `dateutil` with

```
pip install python-datetutil
```

Comment: I personally like relativedelta(months=+1, seconds=-1) seems more obvious what is going on

Comment: You're wrong. `datetime(2014, 2, 1) + relativedelta(days=31)` gives `datetime(2014, 3, 4, 0, 0)`...

Comment: @BenH That is based on the hope (I'm not sure it is specified) that first the `months` is added, then the `seconds` subtracted.  Since they are passed as `**kwargs` I wouldn't rely on that and do a series of separate operations: `now + relative(months=+1) + relative(day=1) + relative(days=-1)` which is unambiguous.

Comment: `last_day = (<datetime_object> + relativedelta(day=31)).day`

Comment: @CarMoreno Yes works with leap years. Try `(datetime(2020,2,2) + relativedelta(day=31)).day`
 yields 29

Comment: For me the `relativedelta(day=+31)` wins;
`datetime(2012, 2, 5) + relativedelta(day=+31)` gave me : **2012-02-29 00:00:00**
`datetime(2012, 2, 5) + relativedelta(months=+1, seconds=-1)` gave me: **2012-03-04 23:59:59**
​

Comment: @BenH This fails. ```relativedelta(months=+1, seconds=-1) ``` or ```relativedelta(months=+1, days=-1) ``` returns the prev day of next month, not 1st.

Answer (score 58):

EDIT: see [my other answer](/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python#43663). It has a better implementation than this one, which I leave here just in case someone's interested in seeing how one might "roll your own" calculator.

@John Millikin gives a good answer, with the added complication of calculating the first day of the next month.

The following isn't particularly elegant, but to figure out the last day of the month that any given date lives in, you could try:

```
def last_day_of_month(date):
    if date.month == 12:
        return date.replace(day=31)
    return date.replace(month=date.month+1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

>>> last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2002, 1, 17))
datetime.date(2002, 1, 31)
>>> last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2002, 12, 9))
datetime.date(2002, 12, 31)
>>> last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2008, 2, 14))
datetime.date(2008, 2, 29)
```

Comment: It sounds silly but How do I get first day of month similarly like this.

Comment: Is it not always 1?

Comment: Yeah but i was confused I was looking something like this : start_date = date(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, 1)

Comment: Ah. `today = datetime.date.today(); start_date = today.replace(day=1)`. You'd want to avoid calling datetime.now twice, in case you called it just before midnight on December 31 and then just after midnight. You'd get 2016-01-01 instead of either 2016-12-01 or 2017-01-01.

Comment: This is very straightforward to understand and returns a datetime instance, which may be useful in many cases. Another advantage is that it works if the input `date` is an instance of `datetime.date`, `datetime.datetime` and also `pandas.Timestamp`.

Answer (score 42):

Using `dateutil.relativedelta` you would get last date of month like this:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
last_date_of_month = datetime(mydate.year, mydate.month, 1) + relativedelta(months=1, days=-1)
```

The idea is to get the first day of the month and use `relativedelta` to go 1 month ahead and 1 day back so you would get the last day of the month you wanted.

Comment: This is a great one line solution. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 22):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>> date  = datetime.datetime.now()

>>> print date
2015-03-06 01:25:14.939574

>>> print date.replace(day = 1)
2015-03-01 01:25:14.939574

>>> print date.replace(day = calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1])
2015-03-31 01:25:14.939574
```

Comment: Great answer! To pull the start & end date                                                             
start_date = datetime.today().replace(day=1).date() ;
last_date = date.replace(day = calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]).date()

Answer (score 22):

In Python 3.8 there is [the undocumented `calendar._monthlen(year, month)` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e70e2ed29703e3d06d0908be5c7836a67bae785/Lib/calendar.py#L171C4-L171C4):

```
>>> calendar._monthlen(2002, 1)
31
>>> calendar._monthlen(2008, 2)
29
>>> calendar._monthlen(2100, 2)
28
```

In python 3.7, it was called `calendar.monthlen(year, month)` without the _underscore.

It is equivalent to [the documented `calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange).

Comment: This does not seem to work on Python 3.8.1: *AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'monthlen'*

Comment: @jeppoo1: yes, it is marked private in [bpo-28292](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0c16f6b307f7607e29b98b8fbb99cbca28f91a48) -- expected for an undocumented function.

Comment: From Python 3.8 on, it's `calendar._monthlen`.

Answer (score 21):

```
from datetime import timedelta
(any_day.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: This is what bugs are made of ;) Try with 31 of January

Comment: @LeartS: it works for me. What happens when you try?

Comment: It works. any_day is Jan 31, we replace day with 1, so Jan 1, add 32 days, we get Feb 2nd, replace with day=1 again and we get Feb 1. Subtract one day and we get Jan 31. I don't see what the issue is. What day do you get?

Answer (score 20):

Another solution would be to do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def last_day_of_month(year, month):
    """ Work out the last day of the month """
    last_days = [31, 30, 29, 28, 27]
    for i in last_days:
        try:
            end = datetime(year, month, i)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            return end.date()
    return None
```

And use the function like this:

```
>>> 
>>> last_day_of_month(2008, 2)
datetime.date(2008, 2, 29)
>>> last_day_of_month(2009, 2)
datetime.date(2009, 2, 28)
>>> last_day_of_month(2008, 11)
datetime.date(2008, 11, 30)
>>> last_day_of_month(2008, 12)
datetime.date(2008, 12, 31)
```

Comment: Too complex, breaks the third rule of the zen of python.

Answer (score 13):

To get the last date of the month we do something like this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import calendar
last_day = date.today().replace(day=calendar.monthrange(date.today().year, date.today().month)[1])
```

Now to explain what we are doing here we will break it into two parts:

first is getting the number of days of the current month for which we use [monthrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) which Blair Conrad has already mentioned his solution:

```
calendar.monthrange(date.today().year, date.today().month)[1]
```

second is getting the last date itself which we do with the help of [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) e.g

```
>>> date.today()
datetime.date(2017, 1, 3)
>>> date.today().replace(day=31)
datetime.date(2017, 1, 31)
```

and when we combine them as mentioned on the top we get a dynamic solution.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This seems the most straightforward.. if you are wiling to give it two lines you can get a nice `date.replace(day=day)` so everyone knows what's going on.

Answer (score 13):

if you are willing to use an external library, check out http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/

U can then get the last day of the month with:

```
import arrow
arrow.utcnow().ceil('month').date()
```

This returns a date object which you can then do your manipulation.

Comment: this is the answer 2023

Answer (score 12):

To me the easier way is using pandas (two lines solution):

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import pandas as pd

    firstday_month = datetime(year, month, 1)
    lastday_month = firstday_month + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
```

Another way to do it is: Taking the first day of the month, then adding one month and discounting one day:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import pandas as pd

    firstday_month = datetime(year, month, 1)
    lastday_month = firstday_month + pd.DateOffset(months=1) - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
```

Answer (score 11):

Use pandas!

```
def isMonthEnd(date):
    return date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) == date

isMonthEnd(datetime(1999, 12, 31))
True
isMonthEnd(pd.Timestamp('1999-12-31'))
True
isMonthEnd(pd.Timestamp(1965, 1, 10))
False
```

Comment: you can also implemented using `pd.series.dt.is_month_end` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.is_month_end.html)

Comment: Pandas datetime object has a specific method for that: `now=datetime.datetime.now(); pd_now = pd.to_datetime(now); print(pd_now.days_in_month)`

Comment: To get the last arbitrary unit of the month, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65148309/).

Answer (score 9):

That's my way - a function with only two lines:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def last_day_of_month(date):
    return date.replace(day=1) + relativedelta(months=1) - relativedelta(days=1)
```

Example:

```
from datetime import date

print(last_day_of_month(date.today()))
>> 2021-09-30
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: 
date.replace(day=1) + relativedelta(months=1, days=-1)

Answer (score 8):

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
start_month = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, 1)
date_on_next_month = start_month + datetime.timedelta(35)
start_next_month = datetime.datetime(date_on_next_month.year, date_on_next_month.month, 1)
last_day_month = start_next_month - datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is another answer. No extra packages required.

```
datetime.date(year + int(month/12), month%12+1, 1)-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Get the first day of the next month and subtract a day from it.

Comment: under-rated answer

Answer (score 7):

The easiest & most reliable way I've found so Far is as:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(2020, 12)[1]
end_dt = datetime(2020, 12, days_in_month)
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use relativedelta
https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

`month_end = <your datetime value within the month> + relativedelta(day=31)`

that will give you the last day.

Comment: By far the simplest answer, making use of the fact `relativedelta` when using an absolute value (the singular field name) will not go past the field's limit.

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest solution for me using just the standard datetime library:

```
import datetime

def get_month_end(dt):
    first_of_month = datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, 1)
    next_month_date = first_of_month + datetime.timedelta(days=32)
    new_dt = datetime.datetime(next_month_date.year, next_month_date.month, 1)
    return new_dt - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and some date math, e.g. subtract a day from the first day of the next month:

```
import datetime

def last_day_of_month(d: datetime.date) -> datetime.date:
    return (
        datetime.date(d.year + d.month//12, d.month % 12 + 1, 1) -
        datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    )
```

Alternatively, you could use [`calendar.monthrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) to get the number of days in a month (taking leap years into account) and update the date accordingly:

```
import calendar, datetime

def last_day_of_month(d: datetime.date) -> datetime.date:
    return d.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1])
```

A quick benchmark shows that the first version is noticeably faster:

```
In [14]: today = datetime.date.today()

In [15]: %timeit last_day_of_month_dt(today)
918 ns ± 3.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit last_day_of_month_calendar(today)
1.4 µs ± 17.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using dateutil.relativedelta

```
dt + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1, day=1, days=-1)
```

`months=1` and `day=1` would shift `dt` to the first date of next month, then `days=-1` would shift the new date to previous date which is exactly the last date of current month.

Answer (score 4):

For me it's the simplest way:

```
selected_date = date(some_year, some_month, some_day)

if selected_date.month == 12: # December
     last_day_selected_month = date(selected_date.year, selected_date.month, 31)
else:
     last_day_selected_month = date(selected_date.year, selected_date.month + 1, 1) - timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the end date yourself. the simple logic is to subtract a day from the start_date of next month. :)

So write a custom method,

```
import datetime

def end_date_of_a_month(date):


    start_date_of_this_month = date.replace(day=1)

    month = start_date_of_this_month.month
    year = start_date_of_this_month.year
    if month == 12:
        month = 1
        year += 1
    else:
        month += 1
    next_month_start_date = start_date_of_this_month.replace(month=month, year=year)

    this_month_end_date = next_month_start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return this_month_end_date
```

Calling,

```
end_date_of_a_month(datetime.datetime.now().date())
```

It will return the end date of this month. Pass any date to this function. returns you the end date of that month.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way (without having to import calendar), is to get the first day of the next month, and then subtract a day from it.

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

thisDate = dt.datetime(2017, 11, 17)

last_day_of_the_month = dt.datetime(thisDate.year, (thisDate + relativedelta(months=1)).month, 1) - dt.timedelta(days=1)
print last_day_of_the_month
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 30, 0, 0)
```

---

**PS:** This code runs faster as compared to the `import calendar`approach; see below:

```
import datetime as dt
import calendar
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

someDates = [dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 10000)]

start1 = dt.datetime.now()
for thisDate in someDates:
    lastDay = dt.datetime(thisDate.year, (thisDate + relativedelta(months=1)).month, 1) - dt.timedelta(days=1)

print ('Time Spent= ', dt.datetime.now() - start1)


start2 = dt.datetime.now()
for thisDate in someDates:
    lastDay = dt.datetime(thisDate.year, 
                          thisDate.month, 
                          calendar.monthrange(thisDate.year, thisDate.month)[1])

print ('Time Spent= ', dt.datetime.now() - start2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Time Spent=  0:00:00.097814
Time Spent=  0:00:00.109791
```

This code assumes that you want the date of the last day of the month (i.e., not just the DD part, but the entire YYYYMMDD date)

Comment: why would you not want to `import calendar`?

Comment: Because it's faster. I have modified my answer above to include this.

Comment: @Vishal you got the concept right but the following line was not: 
```
dt.datetime(thisDate.year, (thisDate + relativedelta(months=1)).month, 1) - dt.timedelta(days=1)
```
especially if the month is at the end of the year. try 
```
    last_date_of_month = \
        first_date_of_month + relativedelta(months=1) - relativedelta(days=1)
``` instead

Answer (score 3):

This does not address the main question, but one nice trick to get the last *weekday* in a month is to use `calendar.monthcalendar`, which returns a matrix of dates, organized with Monday as the first column through Sunday as the last.

```
# Some random date.
some_date = datetime.date(2012, 5, 23)

# Get last weekday
last_weekday = np.asarray(calendar.monthcalendar(some_date.year, some_date.month))[:,0:-2].ravel().max()

print last_weekday
31
```

The whole `[0:-2]` thing is to shave off the weekend columns and throw them out. Dates that fall outside of the month are indicated by 0, so the max effectively ignores them.

The use of `numpy.ravel` is not strictly necessary, but I hate relying on the *mere convention* that `numpy.ndarray.max` will flatten the array if not told which axis to calculate over.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a long (easy to understand) version but takes care of leap years.

```
def last_day_month(year, month):
    leap_year_flag = 0
    end_dates = {
        1: 31,
        2: 28,
        3: 31,
        4: 30,
        5: 31,
        6: 30,
        7: 31,
        8: 31,
        9: 30,
        10: 31,
        11: 30,
        12: 31
    }

    # Checking for regular leap year    
    if year % 4 == 0:
        leap_year_flag = 1
    else:
        leap_year_flag = 0

    # Checking for century leap year    
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            leap_year_flag = 1
        else:
            leap_year_flag = 0
    else:
        pass

    # return end date of the year-month
    if leap_year_flag == 1 and month == 2:
        return 29
    elif leap_year_flag == 1 and month != 2:
        return end_dates[month]
    else:
        return end_dates[month]
```

Comment: you can delete `else: pass` and also you can get rid  `if year % 400 == 0:  leap_year_flag = 1` with minor modifications

Answer (score 3):

How about more simply:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.date(now.year, 1 if now.month==12 else now.month+1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: I like this answer, however you must also increment now.year if month == 12. Should be ```datetime.date(now.year+1 if now.month==12 else now.year, 1 if now.month==12 else now.month+1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)```

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to find interesting solution here. It's possible to get last day of the month providing those relativedelta args: `day=31`,  `days=+1` and `seconds=-1` (which gives you last second of previous day):

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

day_of_febuary = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 21)
last_day_of_febuary = day_of_febuary + relativedelta(day=31, days=+1, seconds=-1)
print(last_day_of_febuary)
# Output: 2022-02-28 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your own small function, this is a good starting point:

```
def eomday(year, month):
    """returns the number of days in a given month"""
    days_per_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    d = days_per_month[month - 1]
    if month == 2 and (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
        d = 29
    return d
```

For this you have to know the rules for the leap years:

- every fourth year
- with the exception of every 100 year
- but again every 400 years

Comment: Sure, but the system libraries already have this data, and should the rules be changed by decree  the updating of the libraries is somebody else's problem.

Comment: Well, possible, but highly unlikely, and even if - it would only bite you in about 2000 years...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Accuracy

Comment: These rules don't work for 500 years into the past I have no confidence that they will stand for thousands of years into the future,

Answer (score 2):

```
import calendar
from time import gmtime, strftime
calendar.monthrange(int(strftime("%Y", gmtime())), int(strftime("%m", gmtime())))[1]
```

Output:

```
31
```

This will print the last day of whatever the current month is. In this example it was 15th May, 2016.  So your output may be different, however the output will be as many days that the current month is.  Great if you want to check the last day of the month by running a daily cron job.

So:

```
import calendar
from time import gmtime, strftime
lastDay = calendar.monthrange(int(strftime("%Y", gmtime())), int(strftime("%m", gmtime())))[1]
today = strftime("%d", gmtime())
lastDay == today
```

Output:

```
False
```

Unless it IS the last day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this way

```
import datetime
import calendar

date=datetime.datetime.now()
month_end_date=datetime.datetime(date.year,date.month,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=calendar.monthrange(date.year,date.month)[1] - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach:

```py
def get_last_day_of_month(mon: int, year: int) -> str:
    '''
    Returns last day of the month.
    '''

    ### Day 28 falls in every month
    res = datetime(month=mon, year=year, day=28)
    ### Go to next month
    res = res + timedelta(days=4)
    ### Subtract one day from the start of the next month
    res = datetime.strptime(res.strftime('%Y-%m-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') - timedelta(days=1)

    return res.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

```bash
>>> get_last_day_of_month(mon=10, year=2022)
... '2022-10-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Pandas, using [`Timestamp.days_in_month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.days_in_month.html) is probably the simplest:

```py
import pandas as pd

> pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=2, day=1).days_in_month

29
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this really helpful using Python, to find the number of days of current month:

First you will have to get current month and current year using datetime

```
current_month = datetime.date.today().month
current_year = datetime.date.today().year
```

Now we get the number of days of current month using:

```
days_current_month = calendar.monthrange(current_year, current_month)[1]
```

If you want to find the number of months of a given month, you just need to apply it for the desirable month/year

For example, if we want to know nº of days of February 2024, we need to do this:

```
current_month = datetime.date.today().replace(month=2).month
current_year = datetime.date.today().replace(year=2024).year



calendar.monthrange(current_year, current_month)[1]
```

output: 29

With this method, it's possible to automate the nº of days of a given month based on a certain date/interval

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in a date range, you can use this:

```
def last_day_of_month(any_days):
    res = []
    for any_day in any_days:
        nday = any_day.days_in_month -any_day.day
        res.append(any_day + timedelta(days=nday))
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based python lambdas:

```
next_month = lambda y, m, d: (y, m + 1, 1) if m + 1 < 13 else ( y+1 , 1, 1)
month_end  = lambda dte: date( *next_month( *dte.timetuple()[:3] ) ) - timedelta(days=1)
```

The `next_month` lambda finds the tuple representation of the first day of the next month, and rolls over to the next year. The `month_end` lambda transforms a date (`dte`) to a tuple, applies `next_month` and creates a new date. Then the "month's end" is just the next month's first day minus `timedelta(days=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below *'get_last_day_of_month(dt)'* will give you this, with date in string format like 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

```
import datetime

def DateTime( d ):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime( d, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

def RelativeDate( start, num_days ):
    d = DateTime( start )
    return str( d + datetime.timedelta( days = num_days ) )

def get_first_day_of_month( dt ):
    return dt[:-2] + '01'

def get_last_day_of_month( dt ):
    fd = get_first_day_of_month( dt )
    fd_next_month = get_first_day_of_month( RelativeDate( fd, 31 ) )
    return RelativeDate( fd_next_month, -1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering there are unequal number of days in different months, here is the standard solution that works for every month.

```
import datetime
ref_date = datetime.today() # or what ever specified date

end_date_of_month = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(ref_date + relativedelta(months=1), '%Y-%m-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') + relativedelta(days=-1)
```

In the above code we are just adding a month to our selected date and then navigating to the first day of that month and then subtracting a day from that date.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```py
df['daysinmonths'] = df['your_date_col'].apply(lambda t: pd.Period(t, freq='S').days_in_month)
```

took reference from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66403016/16607636

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the first day of the month with 0:00 time and don't want to import any special library you can write like this

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# get now time with timezone (optional)
now = datetime.now(pytz.UTC)

# get first day on this month, get last day on prev month and after get first day on prev month with min time
fist_day_with_time = datetime.combine((now.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1), datetime.min.time())
```

Works fine with February 28/29, December - January, and another problem date.

Answer (score 0):

If it only matters if today is the last day of the month and the date does not really matter, then I prefer to use the condition below.

The logic is quite simple. If tomorrow is the first day of the next month, then today is the last day of the actual month. Below two examples of an if-else condition.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

if (datetime.today()+timedelta(days=1)).day == 1:
    print("today is the last day of the month")
else:
    print("today isn't the last day of the month")
```

If timezone awareness is important.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

set(pytz.all_timezones_set)
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")

dt = datetime.today().astimezone(tz=tz)

if (dt+timedelta(days=1)).day == 1:
    print("today is the last day of the month")
else:
    print("today isn't the last day of the month")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more readable than some of the other answers:

```
from datetime import timedelta as td
from datetime import datetime as dt
today = dt.now()
a_day_next_month = dt(today.year, today.month, 27) + td(days=5)
first_day_next_month =  dt(a_day_next_month.year, a_day_next_month.month, 1)
last_day_this_month = first_day_next_month - td(days=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a recursive function.

Is the next day in a different month?  If so, then the current day is the last day of the month.  If the next day is in the same month, try again using that next day.

```
from datetime import timedelta

def last_day_of_month(date):
    if date.month != (date + timedelta(days=1)).month:
        return date
    else:
        return last_day_of_month(date + timedelta(days=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [datetime-month](https://github.com/yitistica/month) package.

```
$ pip install datetime-month
$ python
>>> from month import XMonth
>>> Xmonth(2022, 11).last_date()
datetime.date(2022, 11, 30)
```