# python's datetime and end of the month

Tags: python, datetime

How to create datetime object representing the very last moment of the current month ?

Comment: what precision are you looking for?

Comment: 1 second would be enough

Comment: Longer discussion: [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month/14994380)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a simple trick: Set the date to the first of the *next* month and then subtract one second/hour/day/as much as you need.

Comment: +1: Always works -- never needs to know number of days in the month.  Or year, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

def eom(dt):
    sometime_next_month= dt.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=31)
    start_of_next_month= sometime_next_month.replace(day=1,hour=0,minute=0,second=0)
    return start_of_next_month - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)


>>> eom(datetime.datetime(1972, 2, 1, 23, 50, 50))
datetime.datetime(1972, 2, 29, 23, 59, 59)
>>> eom(datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 31))
datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)
```

Comment: why are you discriminating December?

Comment: You're right. I had the impression that datetime.datetime was doing the *right thing*, but obviously I was wrong. I'll find the code I've written in another answer in SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
selected_date = date(some_year, some_month, some_day)

if selected_date.month == 12: # December
     last_day_selected_month = date(selected_date.year, selected_date.month, 31)
else:
     last_day_selected_month = date(selected_date.year, selected_date.month + 1, 1) - timedelta(days=1)
```

where 'timedelta(days=1)' might be a difference with next month and last moment of the previous month.