# Return datetime object of previous month

Tags: python, date

If only timedelta had a month argument in it's constructor.  So what's the simplest way to do this?

**EDIT:** I wasn't thinking too hard about this as was pointed out below.  Really what I wanted was any day in the last month because eventually I'm going to grab the year and month only.  So given a datetime object, what's the simplest way to return **any datetime object that falls in the previous month**?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try this:

```
def monthdelta(date, delta):
    m, y = (date.month+delta) % 12, date.year + ((date.month)+delta-1) // 12
    if not m: m = 12
    d = min(date.day, [31,
        29 if y%4==0 and (not y%100==0 or y%400 == 0) else 28,
        31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][m-1])
    return date.replace(day=d,month=m, year=y)

>>> for m in range(-12, 12):
    print(monthdelta(datetime.now(), m))

    
2009-08-06 16:12:27.823000
2009-09-06 16:12:27.855000
2009-10-06 16:12:27.870000
2009-11-06 16:12:27.870000
2009-12-06 16:12:27.870000
2010-01-06 16:12:27.870000
2010-02-06 16:12:27.870000
2010-03-06 16:12:27.886000
2010-04-06 16:12:27.886000
2010-05-06 16:12:27.886000
2010-06-06 16:12:27.886000
2010-07-06 16:12:27.886000
2010-08-06 16:12:27.901000
2010-09-06 16:12:27.901000
2010-10-06 16:12:27.901000
2010-11-06 16:12:27.901000
2010-12-06 16:12:27.901000
2011-01-06 16:12:27.917000
2011-02-06 16:12:27.917000
2011-03-06 16:12:27.917000
2011-04-06 16:12:27.917000
2011-05-06 16:12:27.917000
2011-06-06 16:12:27.933000
2011-07-06 16:12:27.933000
>>> monthdelta(datetime(2010,3,30), -1)
datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 28, 0, 0)
>>> monthdelta(datetime(2008,3,30), -1)
datetime.datetime(2008, 2, 29, 0, 0)
```

**Edit** Corrected to handle the day as well.

**Edit** See also the answer from puzzlement which points out a simpler calculation for `d`:

```
d = min(date.day, calendar.monthrange(y, m)[1])
```

Comment: If I have it right `((date.month+delta-1) % 12)+1` works and means the `if not m: m = 12` can get removed

Comment: @dan-klasson can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The first one is not simple. Also, one can easily do this with datetime and timedelta.

Comment: Yes, after the OP edited it becomes clear that what they want can be done just by `dt - timedelta(days=dt.day)` As originally phrased though it sounded like they wanted to be able to subtract an arbitrary number of months and that is a bit harder.

Comment: I think the calculation for leap years is incorrect - it should be `29 if y%4==0 and (not y%100==0 or y%400 == 0) else 28`.  e.g. 1600 is a leap year while 1700 is not

Answer (score 249):

You can use the third party [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) module (PyPI entry [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil)).

```
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-03-31", "%Y-%m-%d")
d2 = d - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
print d2
```

output:

```
2013-02-28 00:00:00
```

Comment: I am confused with the param `month` and `months` in dateutil.    Subtract with param `month` doesn't work but `months` works             `In [23]: created_datetime__lt - relativedelta(months=1) 
Out[23]: datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'Etc/GMT-8'>)

In [24]: created_datetime__lt - relativedelta(month=1) 
Out[24]: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'Etc/GMT-8'>)`

Comment: @SiminJie: I think using `months` will make a difference of 1 month. Using `month` will set the month to 1 (eg January), regardless of the month of the input.

Answer (score 111):

After the original question's edit to "any datetime object in the previous month", you can do it pretty easily by subtracting 1 day from the first of the month.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def a_day_in_previous_month(dt):
   return dt.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: you could use `dt.replace(day=1) - timedelta(1)`

Comment: or `dt - timedelta(days=dt.day)`

Answer (score 54):

A vectorized, pandas solution is very simple:

`df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)`

Comment: Thank you! It helped me easily add/substract a month to/from my set of dates!

Comment: This is nice if you can use `pandas`. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

A variation on [Duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424899/whats-the-simplest-way-to-subtract-a-month-from-a-date-in-python/3425124#3425124) (I don't have sufficient reputation to comment), which uses calendar.monthrange to dramatically simplify the computation of the last day of the month:

```
import calendar
def monthdelta(date, delta):
    m, y = (date.month+delta) % 12, date.year + ((date.month)+delta-1) // 12
    if not m: m = 12
    d = min(date.day, calendar.monthrange(y, m)[1])
    return date.replace(day=d,month=m, year=y)
```

Info on monthrange from [Get Last Day of the Month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python)

Comment: I think you can also replace the first two lines of the function with these `y, m = divmod(date.year * 12 + date.month + delta - 1, 12); m += 1` if that looks cleaner for you.

Answer (score 25):

I think the simple way is to use DateOffset from Pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd
date_1 = pd.to_datetime("2013-03-31", format="%Y-%m-%d") - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
```

The result will be a Timestamp object

Comment: That is the most intuitive solution

Comment: I actually think the result is a `pandas.Timestamp` object. But you can convert it into a datetime easily.

Comment: @hlin117 yes, that is correct, I will correct it now

Answer (score 22):

> If only timedelta had a month argument
>   in it's constructor. So what's the
>   simplest way to do this?

What do you want the result to be when you subtract a month from, say, a date that is March 30?  That is the problem with adding or subtracting months: months have different lengths!  In some application an exception is appropriate in such cases, in others "the last day of the previous month" is OK to use (but that's truly crazy arithmetic, when subtracting a month then adding a month is **not** overall a no-operation!), in others yet you'll want to keep in addition to the date some indication about the fact, e.g., "I'm saying Feb 28 but I really would want Feb 30 if it existed", so that adding or subtracting another month to that can set things right again (and the latter obviously requires a custom class holding a data plus s/thing else).

There can be no real solution that is tolerable for all applications, and you have not told us what your specific app's needs are for the semantics of this wretched operation, so there's not much more help that we can provide here.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Was just joking about timedelta having an argument for that.  I wonder if the same logic applies for not having arguments for hours or minutes.  Technically a day isn't exactly 24 hours.

Comment: PHP [handles that](http://codepad.org/hLeHWRgz) by adding 2 days to Feb 28th, and it goes to March 2nd. There're conventions for this, let me find them real quick

Comment: It gets even more interesting if you are calculating dates for currency exchange: e.g. you might need to find a date say 3 or 6 months in the future, but it also has to be a working day in both countries (not Friday in Moslem countries) and not a bank holiday in either country.

Comment: @Bialecki: `datetime` modules assumes that a day is exactly 24 hours (no leap seconds)

Answer (score 11):

If all you want is any day in the last month, the simplest thing you can do is subtract the number of days from the current date, which will give you the last day of the previous month.

For instance, starting with any date:

```
>>> import datetime                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> today = datetime.date.today()                                                                                                                                                   
>>> today
datetime.date(2016, 5, 24)
```

Subtracting the days of the current date we get:

```
>>> last_day_previous_month = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.day)
>>> last_day_previous_month
datetime.date(2016, 4, 30)
```

This is enough for your simplified need of any day in the last month.

But now that you have it, you can also get any day in the month, including the same day you started with (i.e. more or less the same as subtracting a month):

```
>>> same_day_last_month = last_day_previous_month.replace(day=today.day)
>>> same_day_last_month
datetime.date(2016, 4, 24)
```

Of course, you need to be careful with 31st on a 30 day month or the days missing from February (and take care of leap years), but that's also easy to do:

```
>>> a_date = datetime.date(2016, 3, 31)                                                                                                                                             
>>> last_day_previous_month = a_date - datetime.timedelta(days=a_date.day)
>>> a_date_minus_month = (
...     last_day_previous_month.replace(day=a_date.day)
...     if a_date.day < last_day_previous_month.day
...     else last_day_previous_month
... )
>>> a_date_minus_month
datetime.date(2016, 2, 29)
```

Answer (score 4):

Returns last day of last month:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.now().day)
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 30, 14, 13, 15, 67582)
```

Returns the same day last month:

```
>>> x = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.now().day)
>>> x.replace(day=datetime.datetime.now().day)
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7, 14, 22, 14, 362421)
```

Answer (score 4):

For most use cases, what about

```py
from datetime import date

current_date =date.today()
current_month = current_date.month
last_month = current_month - 1 if current_month != 1 else 12  
today_a_month_ago = date(current_date.year, last_month, current_date.day)
```

That seems the simplest to me.

*Note:* I've added the second to last line so that it would work if the current month is January as per @Nick's comment

*Note 2:* In most cases, if the current date is the 31st of a given month the result will be an invalid date as the previous month would not have 31 days (Except for July & August), as noted by @OneCricketeer

Comment: That's a great solution! You would need to fix this undefined `a`.

Comment: Thanks pointing at that, `a` should be equal to `current_date`. I will fix it now :)

Comment: What about if the current date is in January?? The year won't change.

Comment: Also doesn't work consistently on months with 31 days or March 29+

Comment: Thanks for the comments Nick and @OneCricketeer, I've addressed your comments as best as I've could without overcomplicating the code.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for government fiscal years where Q4 starts October 1st.  Note I convert the date into quarters and undo it as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = '1/1/2020'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])              #returns 2020-01-01
df['NewDate'] = df.Date - pd.DateOffset(months=3)    #returns 2019-10-01 <---- answer

# For fun, change it to FY Quarter '2019Q4'
df['NewDate'] = df['NewDate'].dt.year.astype(str) + 'Q' + df['NewDate'].dt.quarter.astype(str)

# Convert '2019Q4' back to 2019-10-01
df['NewDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.NewDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner ?

`previous_month_date = (current_date - datetime.timedelta(days=current_date.day+1)).replace(day=current_date.day)`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Way that i have tried Just now

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone





current = timezone.now()
if current.month == 1:
     month = 12
else:
     month = current.month - 1
current = datetime(current.year, month, current.day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some [code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577274-subtract-or-add-a-month-to-a-datetimedate-or-datet/) to do just that. Haven't tried it out myself...

```
def add_one_month(t):
    """Return a `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` (as given) that is
    one month earlier.

    Note that the resultant day of the month might change if the following
    month has fewer days:

        >>> add_one_month(datetime.date(2010, 1, 31))
        datetime.date(2010, 2, 28)
    """
    import datetime
    one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    one_month_later = t + one_day
    while one_month_later.month == t.month:  # advance to start of next month
        one_month_later += one_day
    target_month = one_month_later.month
    while one_month_later.day < t.day:  # advance to appropriate day
        one_month_later += one_day
        if one_month_later.month != target_month:  # gone too far
            one_month_later -= one_day
            break
    return one_month_later

def subtract_one_month(t):
    """Return a `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` (as given) that is
    one month later.

    Note that the resultant day of the month might change if the following
    month has fewer days:

        >>> subtract_one_month(datetime.date(2010, 3, 31))
        datetime.date(2010, 2, 28)
    """
    import datetime
    one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    one_month_earlier = t - one_day
    while one_month_earlier.month == t.month or one_month_earlier.day > t.day:
        one_month_earlier -= one_day
    return one_month_earlier
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a (year,month) tuple, where month goes from 1-12, try this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> today = datetime.today()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 6, 10, 15, 21, 310000)
>>> thismonth = today.year, today.month
>>> thismonth
(2010, 8)
>>> lastmonth = lambda (yr,mo): [(y,m+1) for y,m in (divmod((yr*12+mo-2), 12),)][0]
>>> lastmonth(thismonth)
(2010, 7)
>>> lastmonth( (2010,1) )
(2009, 12)
```

Assumes there are 12 months in every year.

Answer (score 0):

```
def month_sub(year, month, sub_month):
    result_month = 0
    result_year = 0
    if month > (sub_month % 12):
        result_month = month - (sub_month % 12)
        result_year = year - (sub_month / 12)
    else:
        result_month = 12 - (sub_month % 12) + month
        result_year = year - (sub_month / 12 + 1)
    return (result_year, result_month)

>>> month_sub(2015, 7, 1)    
(2015, 6)
>>> month_sub(2015, 7, -1)
(2015, 8)
>>> month_sub(2015, 7, 13)
(2014, 6)
>>> month_sub(2015, 7, -14)
(2016, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Used the following code to go back n Months from a specific Date:

```
your_date =  datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y-%m-%d")  #to convert date(2016-01-01) to timestamp
start_date=your_date    #start from current date

#Calculate Month
for i in range(0,n):    #n = number of months you need to go back
    start_date=start_date.replace(day=1)    #1st day of current month
    start_date=start_date-timedelta(days=1) #last day of previous month

#Calculate Day
if(start_date.day>your_date.day):   
    start_date=start_date.replace(day=your_date.day)            

print start_date
```

For eg:
input date = 28/12/2015
Calculate 6 months previous date.

I) CALCULATE MONTH: 
This step will give you the start_date as 30/06/2015.
**Note** that after the calculate month step you will get the last day of the required month.

II)CALCULATE DAY:
Condition **if(start_date.day>your_date.day)**  checks whether the day from input_date is present in the required month. This handles condition where input date is 31(or 30) and the required month has less than 31(or 30 in case of feb) days. It handles leap year case as well(For Feb). After this step you will get result as 28/06/2015

If this condition is not satisfied, the start_date remains the last date of the previous month. So if you give 31/12/2015 as input date and want 6 months previous date, it will give you 30/06/2015

Answer (score 0):

You can use below given function to get date before/after X month.

```
from datetime import date

def next_month(given_date, month):
    yyyy = int(((given_date.year * 12 + given_date.month) + month)/12)
    mm = int(((given_date.year * 12 + given_date.month) + month)%12)

    if mm == 0:
        yyyy -= 1
        mm = 12

    return given_date.replace(year=yyyy, month=mm)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    today = date.today()
    print(today)

    for mm in [-12, -1, 0, 1, 2, 12, 20 ]:
        next_date = next_month(today, mm)
        print(next_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is quite readable:

```
def month_delta(dt, delta):
    year_delta, month = divmod(dt.month + delta, 12)

    if month == 0:
        # convert a 0 to december
        month = 12
        if delta < 0:
            # if moving backwards, then it's december of last year
            year_delta -= 1

    year = dt.year + year_delta

    return dt.replace(month=month, year=year)

for delta in range(-20, 21):
    print(delta, "->", month_delta(datetime(2011, 1, 1), delta))

-20 -> 2009-05-01 00:00:00
-19 -> 2009-06-01 00:00:00
-18 -> 2009-07-01 00:00:00
-17 -> 2009-08-01 00:00:00
-16 -> 2009-09-01 00:00:00
-15 -> 2009-10-01 00:00:00
-14 -> 2009-11-01 00:00:00
-13 -> 2009-12-01 00:00:00
-12 -> 2010-01-01 00:00:00
-11 -> 2010-02-01 00:00:00
-10 -> 2010-03-01 00:00:00
-9 -> 2010-04-01 00:00:00
-8 -> 2010-05-01 00:00:00
-7 -> 2010-06-01 00:00:00
-6 -> 2010-07-01 00:00:00
-5 -> 2010-08-01 00:00:00
-4 -> 2010-09-01 00:00:00
-3 -> 2010-10-01 00:00:00
-2 -> 2010-11-01 00:00:00
-1 -> 2010-12-01 00:00:00
0 -> 2011-01-01 00:00:00
1 -> 2011-02-01 00:00:00
2 -> 2011-03-01 00:00:00
3 -> 2011-04-01 00:00:00
4 -> 2011-05-01 00:00:00
5 -> 2011-06-01 00:00:00
6 -> 2011-07-01 00:00:00
7 -> 2011-08-01 00:00:00
8 -> 2011-09-01 00:00:00
9 -> 2011-10-01 00:00:00
10 -> 2011-11-01 00:00:00
11 -> 2012-12-01 00:00:00
12 -> 2012-01-01 00:00:00
13 -> 2012-02-01 00:00:00
14 -> 2012-03-01 00:00:00
15 -> 2012-04-01 00:00:00
16 -> 2012-05-01 00:00:00
17 -> 2012-06-01 00:00:00
18 -> 2012-07-01 00:00:00
19 -> 2012-08-01 00:00:00
20 -> 2012-09-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I came across the following algorithm which works very well for incrementing and decrementing months on either a `date` or `datetime`.

**CAVEAT**: This will fail if `day` is not available in the new month. I use this on date objects where `day == 1` always.

Python 3.x:

```py
def increment_month(d, add=1):
    return date(d.year+(d.month+add-1)//12, (d.month+add-1) % 12+1, 1)
```

For Python 2.7 change the `//12` to just `/12` since integer division is implied.

I recently used this in a defaults file when a script started to get these useful globals:

```py
MONTH_THIS = datetime.date.today()
MONTH_THIS = datetime.date(MONTH_THIS.year, MONTH_THIS.month, 1)

MONTH_1AGO = datetime.date(MONTH_THIS.year+(MONTH_THIS.month-2)//12,
                           (MONTH_THIS.month-2) % 12+1, 1)

MONTH_2AGO = datetime.date(MONTH_THIS.year+(MONTH_THIS.month-3)//12,
                           (MONTH_THIS.month-3) % 12+1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to substract "n_months" months to a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def substract_months(original_date: datetime, n_months:int) -> datetime:
    ref_date = original_date
    for i in range(0, number_of_months):
        ref_date = (ref_date.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
    ref_date = ref_date.replace(day=original_date.day)
    return ref_date
```

You can use it as:

```
print(substract_months(original_date=datetime(2022, 11, 16), number_of_months=2))
```

which returns:

```
2022-09-16 00:00:00
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import datetime
date_str = '08/01/2018'
format_str = '%d/%m/%Y'
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, format_str)   
datetime_obj.replace(month=datetime_obj.month-1)
```

Simple solution, no need for special libraries.

Comment: Won't work when the date is something like 31st March.

Comment: Or like 1st january

Answer (score -4):

You could do it in two lines like this:

```
now = datetime.now()
last_month = datetime(now.year, now.month - 1, now.day)
```

remember the imports

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: What if it's Jan?