# Create a dynamic sql query where one condition is generated from parameters given

Tags: python, dynamic-sql

I have the below SQL query to fetch data based on month_id which contains the year and month:

```
sql_hours = str("""select * from monthly_hours where month_id IN  \
                          (201701,201702,201703,201704,201705,201706,201707,201708,201709,201710,201711,201712) and class = 'Optimal';""")
```

the base table looks like:

```
device_id   month_id    group   hours   tier
53          201705      TX      11.31   Optimal
28          201701      WS      31.56   Sub - Optimal
32          201706      WX      2.93    Optimal
57          201709      TS      2.68    Optimal 
28          201702      OE      0.70    Optimal
```

Here based on the number of months user wants to take data of and current month the values inside IN() would change.
Ex. Current `month_id is 201802` and if `no_of_months = 6`, my query would become:

```
sql_hours = str("""select * from monthly_hours where month_id IN  \
                          (201707,201708,201709,201710,201711,201712) and class = 'Optimal';""")
```

There is a lag of 2 months for data and hence the latest data would be of 201712(for current month of Feb.However in March the latest data would be of 201801). so the `month_id's have to fall within 201707 and 201712`.
If the `no_of_months = 12` then the month_id's have to `fall within 201701 and 201712.`

Can someone please help me with this? I am not sure how so much parameterization of the sql query can be done in python!!

Comment: I'm sorry but I just can't get what your question is _exactly_ ?

Comment: select the months for the IN clause based on the number of months specified. So if number of months is 6, from Feb,2018(current_dates_month) to Sep,2017 will be the list of months used for filtering on month_id.

Comment: What does it have to do with SQL then ? You just want to generate a list of "YYYYMM" strings (hint: you want strings here, if you're using ints you're doing it wrong, those are numeric codes but NOT ints) starting from one YYYYMM and going back N months. There's nothing magical nor overly complex here and there are already quite a few questions about such date manipulations, cf   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424899/whats-the-simplest-way-to-subtract-a-month-from-a-date-in-python for example

Answer (score 1):

you could update the query string with the variable, using `.format()` to parametrize, example:

```
dates = '201707,201708,201709,201710,201711,201712'

sql_hours = str("select * from monthly_hours where month_id IN  \
                          ({}) and class = 'Optimal';".format(dates))
```

Comment: Only do this if you're 101% sure the variable comes from your very own code and not from any external (user, file, request, whatever) input - unless you don't mind opening your app to SQL injections of course (http://bobby-tables.com/)