# Getting the date as YYYY-MM minus one month

Tags: python-3.x, date

If I use this:

```
YYYYMMnow = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m')
```

I get as output

```
2020-11
```

As of today is November 2020

I want a formula that gives me, YYYY-MM minus one month

it would be an output like

```
2020-10
```

or in January, from 2021-01, it would return 2020-12

Comment: Duplicate [whats-the-simplest-way-to-subtract-a-month-from-a-date-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424899/whats-the-simplest-way-to-subtract-a-month-from-a-date-in-python)

Comment: @PatrickArtner significant difference since day-of-month is excluded here

Comment: @bradSolomon Thats not a difference - that is a matter of outputting. Plenty of posts for printing dates on SO as well! And he solved the output already: `datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m')` so the only thing left is subtracting one month wich is handled by the dupe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to subtract a month from a date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424899/whats-the-simplest-way-to-subtract-a-month-from-a-date-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Logic:

- Replace the day with 1. Then you don't run into issues such as asking Python ["what's one month before March 30"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3425016/7954504)
- Subtract 10 days; the day element of the result is irrelevant
- Truncate to YYYY-MM

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> (datetime.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=10)).strftime('%Y-%m')
'2020-10'
>>> (datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=5).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=10)).strftime('%Y-%m')
'2020-02'
```

Comment: `(datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=5).replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=30)).strftime('%Y-%m')` >> `'2020-01'` I think just subtracting one day, to get the month should be enough instead, if you're just reseting it to the first anyway.

Comment: Ah, good catch @HampusLarsson