# How to find number of days in the current month

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Last Day of the Month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python)

How can I get the number of days in the current month? I.e.,if the current month is "Jan 2012" I should get 31. If it is "Feb 2012" I should get 29.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python

Comment: @peter nice I was just looking at http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html, must have glazed passed `monthrange`

Comment: `def days_in_month(): return 29`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As Peter mentioned, `calendar.monthrange(year, month)` returns weekday (0-6 ~ Mon-Sun) and number of days (28-31) for `year`, `month`.

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(2012,1)[1]
31
>>> calendar.monthrange(2012,2)[1]
29
```

**Edit**: updated answer to return the number of days of the current month

```
>>> import calendar
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> calendar.monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1]
29
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!but i dont want to hardcode the dates like (2012,1)..I want it to be the system date

Comment: Thank you so much.This works for windows..i am using ubuntu 11.10..and import calender produces the error "No module named calender"..any ideas??? or is there an alternate method of getting this done without using 'calender'???

Comment: Note, it is `calendAr` instead of `calendEr`!