# Why is this solving to 30 when it should be 28?

Tags: python, if-statement

I know this is very rudimentary, but I am new to programming and this is driving me NUTS.

Can someone tell me why I am getting "30" and not "28" as the answer to this?

```
def days_in_month(month):
    if month == 4 or 6 or 9 or 11:
        return 30
    else:
        if month == 2:
            return 28
    else:
        return 31

print(days_in_month(2))
```

Comment: Sorry for the possible duplicate, like I said I am new to coding (and this site) and therefore also new to searching for answers here. I'm not sure I would have thought to word it that way.

Comment: Your computation will not be correct for leap years.
And, as many times, there is a module to get you what you want; see:
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481136/how-to-find-number-of-days-in-the-current-month

Comment: I understand that there is a module for leap year. I am just doing it myself as part of a free online course to learn python. What specifically would be wrong about the is_leap_year function? Edit: I'm an idiot -- I created a function for leap years but didn't put it in the code as I felt it wasn't relevant to the question. Thank you for pointing that out, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not quite correct (it's syntactically valid but doesn't do what you expect it to do):

```
if month == 4 or 6 or 9 or 11:
```

Change it to:

```
if month in {4, 6, 9, 11}:
```

Also, your top `if` statement has two `else` clauses. This is not valid syntax. I'd suggest taking a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) to learn about the `if` statement.

Comment: it should be written `elif`

Comment: If you're constructing a literal, any reason to use a set over a tuple or list?

Comment: Not sure how faster or slower it is but you don't have to scan for the value in a set. It could be faster.

Comment: @NickT: I think in this instance they're basically equivalent. I think using a set is slightly preferable for didactic reasons.