# How would you get the xth weekday of a given month in python?

Tags: python, datetime

If I have a month (2017,5), and I would like to get the 10th weekday of that month -- is there a quick way to do it?  Brute force, I know I could loop through every calendar day of time and create a massive mapping. But wondering if there is an easier way.

Sorry if this has been asked before! Can't seem to find a solution in python.

Comment: Sorry but what is a weekday? Not clear what you want, 10th of may, or do you want the day of the week name, e.g. monday?

Comment: Ah, should have been more clear.  So, I don't want the 10th of may. But instead I want the function to return a datetime which is the 10th day in may excluding weekends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `datetime.date` object you can use the [`.isoweekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) method to check the day of the week, all weekdays return values `<=5` so:

```
def is_business_day(day):
    return day.isoweekday() < 5
```

You can use it like this to find all weekdays in a given month

```
In [29]: filter(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] else None, 
                [(d, is_business_day(datetime.date(2017,5,d))) 
                 for d in range(1,31)])
Out[29]: 
[(1, True),
 (2, True),
 (3, True),
 (4, True),
 (8, True),
 (9, True),
 (10, True),
 (11, True),
 (15, True),
 (16, True),
 (17, True),
 (18, True),
 (22, True),
 (23, True),
 (24, True),
 (25, True),
 (29, True),
 (30, True)]
```

This code isn't safe though. It does not check the boundaries of a month.

```
In [34]: filter(lambda x: x[1] if x[1] else None, 
                [(d, is_business_day(datetime.date(2017,2,d))) 
                  for d in range(1,31)])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-486d782346bd> in <module>()
----> 1 filter(lambda x: x[1] if x[1] else None, [(d, is_business_day(datetime.date(2017,2,d))) for d in range(1,31)])

ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

So you will have to make some more logic to figure the boundaries of months.

To figure out the boundaries of each month see [How to find number of days in the current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481136/how-to-find-number-of-days-in-the-current-month)

You can also improve the outputted formatted a bit:

```
In [43]: [d for d in range(1,31) if is_business_day(datetime.date(2017,5,d))]
Out[43]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29, 30]
```

### update, now the last comment of the OP is published, get the Xth business day:

Building on the latest list comperhansion, if `x` is the 9 business day:

```
In [6]: [d for d in range(1,31) if 
         is_business_day(datetime.date(2017,5,d))][9-1]
Out[6]: 15

In [7]: x=9

In [8]: [d for d in range(1,31) if 
         is_business_day(datetime.date(2017,5,d))][x-1]
Out[8]: 15
```

Comment: You can do it too. But I find it a bit more readable, if you don't care or know the details of ISO standard. `_days_in_month`! That is awesome!

Comment: oh wait... `del (... _days_in_month, ...)` ..... dang it >:( it is only available if `_datetime` the C implementation can't be loaded.

Comment: seems also only datetime.py in Python3

Comment: But it's available in calendar

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement a basic algorithm to solve it, there's quite a few but there's a very simple method listed on this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week