# python datetime: How to get next period (using aliases such as 'D', 'M')

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to get from a date to the next period? I.e. I am looking for a funaction `next` that takes

```
now = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 15, 0, 0)
```

to

```
next(now, 'D') = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 16, 0, 0) #moving to next day
next(now, 'M') = datetime.datetime(2013,12,31) #moving to next month (day doesn't matter really)
```

I have tried using Day and MonthEnd from pandas.tseries.offsets but MonthEnd will convert to MonthEnd of the given month, not next month. Is there any simple way to do this?

EDIT: I know this is fairly easy for months. Or days. The problem is, what if I then decide to use business days (Alias 'B')? Or BusinessMonthEnd ('BM')? Surely there should be a method that works for any of these, without having to think about how to implement business days?

Comment: No, there is no such method. And 'next month' is ambigous, what *is* 'next month' from 2013-01-31?

Comment: Take a look at the `dateutil` package, it has a relativedelta object that'll do most of this, including making decisions about the tricky parts.

Comment: Next month from 2013-01-31 should be 2013-02-x. Think about it in periods, i.e. for a monthly period days don't matter.

Comment: Yet it does matter, because you didn't specify the `x` there. In a leap year, would that be 28 or 29?

Comment: And other processes require adding 30 days, instead of assuming you stay within month boundaries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43663/197657 shows a way to get the number of days in a month, making the rest more or less trivial as they don't vary.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `dateutil`, like this:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

one_day = date.today() + relativedelta (days =+ 1)
one_month = date.today() + relativedelta( months =+ 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) objects.

Finding the next day is pretty easy, as you just have to add 24 hours:

```
next=now+datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
```

The next week is simple as well with days=7, but the next month is a bit tricky because a timedelta with days=31 will sometimes fire you two months later.

Comment: Combine with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43663/197657 and you have everything you need.