# Adding month, day, year to a date

Tags: python

I need to write a class syntax, to be able to add days, months.. to a date.
currently I only have this:

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, day=1, month=1, year=2015):
        self.day = day
        self.mon = month
        self.year = year
    def printUS(self):
        print self.mon , "/" , self.day , "/" , self.year
    def printUK(self):
        print self.day , "." , self.mon , "." , str(self.year)[2:]
    def AddDay(self,n=1):
```

I am confused how to write the last function in a way to add days for each month correctly not to exceed the days of month or year.
I rather not use any other modules, since I have not learned them at all.
I don't have more than a month basic programming experience,and never had previous experience before.

Comment: Can you please select the section of source in your question, and click the source format button? It looks like `{}`

Comment: class Date:
 def __init__(self, day, month, year=2015):
  self.day = day
  self.month = month
  self.year = year
  self.monthlength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
 def printUS(self):
  print self.month , "/" , self.day , "/" , self.year
 def printUK(self):
  print self.day , "." , self.month , "." , str(self.year)[2:]
 def AddDay(self,n=1):
  if (self.day) + n > (self.monthlength[self.month]):
          self.day = self.day + n - self.monthlength[self.month]
      else:
           self.day = self.day + n
import sys
mydate=Date(1,11,2015)
mydate.AddDay(31)
mydate.printUS()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
class Date(object):
    def __init__(self, day=1, month=1, year=2015):
        self.day = day
        self.mon = month
        self.year = year
    def __str__(self):
        return "Date is: %s %s %s"%(self.day,self.mon,self.year)
    def IsLeapYear(self):
        """
        function returns 1 if self.year is leap,0 if it's not
        """
        if(not (self.year%400) or (not(self.year%4) and self.year%100)):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    #values by each month whether it's leap year or not
    monthlength = (
        [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
        [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    )

        #the function you probably were looking for
    def AddDay(self, n):
        days=n
        leap_year=self.IsLeapYear()
        while(self.day+days>=Date.monthlength[leap_year][self.mon-1]):
            days=days-(Date.monthlength[leap_year][self.mon-1]-self.day)
            self.day=0
            self.mon+=1
            if (self.mon>12):
                self.mon=1
                self.year+=1
            leap_year=self.IsLeapYear()
        else:
            self.day+=days
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, although I put my days to the corresponding month in a dict.

Answer (score 1):

You are off to a good start. I recommend looking into the modulo operator. You can use it to increment months after calculating the number of days in a given month after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python). If you have any questions, feel free to comment them.

Answer (score 0):

For that you could create a function that determines the number of days in a given month; i.e. num_days(month, year) -> int numOfDays

Then you could simply change the method to your Date class, add_days(self, n=1), to check the value of num_days(self.mon, self.year) and then if self.day + n is greater than that value, increment self.mon and subtract the value from n, using the difference as the new value for self.day.

The real trick is creating the num_days function, because in leap years February will have a different number of days.  I recommend looking up the full technical definition of a leap year because it's slightly more complicated than just checking if it's divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

to keep it very simple you could make an array with the length of each month.

```
monthlength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, ...]
```

And then check which month it is in your add day function. so in the end looks like this:

```
monthlength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, ...]

def AddDay(self, n=1):
    if self.day + n > self.monthlength[self.month]:
         self.day = self.day + n - self.monthlength[self.month]
         self.month = self.month + 1
         if self.month == 13:
              self.month = 1
              self.year = self.year + 1
              if self.year%4 == 0:
                  self.monthlength[1] = 29
              else:
                  self.monthlength[1] = 28

    else:
         self.day = self.day + n
```

Comment: And what is about leap years?

Comment: right now i am at this level, and what i get is adding to the day numbers until adding 31 days to the first day of the month, but anything after that , it starts over from day one of the same month. I need to make this work until passing the last day of that month and be able to add to the month as well, this is what i have so far, ant help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Edited the Answer so it counts now also months and years. Also considering leap years (to be 100% correct you would have to ignore the years 1900, 2100, 2200, ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, day, month, year=2015):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.monthlength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    def printUS(self):
        print self.month , "/" , self.day , "/" , self.year
    def printUK(self):
        print self.day , "." , self.month , "." , str(self.year)[2:]
    def AddDay(self,n=1):
        if (self.day) + n > (self.monthlength[self.month]):
                self.day = self.day + n - self.monthlength[self.month]
            else:
                self.day = self.day + n
import sys
mydate=Date(1,11,2015)
mydate.AddDay(31)
mydate.printUS()
```