# Pandas date ranges and averaging the counts

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have the below pandas dataframe

```
stdate      enddate  count  
2004-01-04  2004-01-10  68  
2004-01-11  2004-01-17  100   
2004-01-18  2004-01-24  83  
2004-01-25  2004-01-31  56    
2004-02-01  2004-02-07  56  
2004-02-08  2004-02-14  68    
2004-02-15  2004-02-21  81  
2004-02-22  2004-02-28  68    
2004-02-29  2004-03-06  76
```

I want to take an average of the count based on the month:

that is I wanted it like:

```
date    count
2004-01 (306/25-4)
2004-02 (349/28-01)
```

for example the second month as the enddate 3, (I need help in aggregarting this counts using pandas)

Comment: How would you split it between the groups if the start date was at some month, and the end date at another? Proportionally to the days?

Comment: Yes, If we can do that It will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that complicated, but there is a bit of work, and I think you should ditch `pandas` for most of the calculation, and build a dataframe right at the end.

Suppose you have two `datetime` objects, `b` and `e`. The difference between them in days is

```
(e - b).days
```

This gives you how the count of a row is divided by days.

Also, given a month, you can find the last day of the month [using the `calendar` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python).

So, you could do the following:

```
counts_per_month = {}
def process_row(b, e, count):
    ...
    # Find how count splits between the months, 
    #    update counts_per_month accordingly
```

Now call

```
df.apply(lambda r: process_row(r.stdate, r.enddate, r.count), axis=1)
```

at which point `counts_per_month` will contain your data. Finish off by calling [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).