# Get the last date of each month in a list of dates in Python

Tags: python, date, numpy

I'm using Python 2.7, PyCharm and Anaconda,

I have a `list` of dates and I'd like to retrieve the last date of each month present in the array.

Are there any functions or libraries that could help me to do this?

I read the dates from a CSV file and stored them as `datetime`.

I have the following code:

```
Dates=[]
Dates1=[]
for date in dates:
    temp=xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(date),0)
    Dates1.append(datetime.datetime(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2]))

for date in Dates1:
    if not (date<startDate or date>endDate):
        Dates.append(date)
```

To make it clear, suppose I have:

```
Dates = [2015-01-20, 2015-01-15, 2015-01-17, 2015-02-21, 2015-02-06]
```

(Consider it being in `datetime` format.)

The list I'd like to retrieve is:

```
[2015-01-20, 2015-02-21]
```

So far I've googled around, especially in Stack Overflow, but I could only find answers to how I could get the last date of each month, but not from a user-specified list.

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote that produces these dates? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Find the actual last date of the month and substract each date from that date. Smallest number is the closest.

Comment: Please see my answer. If that works for you, could you please accept it and upvote it?

Comment: I think the question is not completely clear. Do you want the last valid date for a particular month (so if you have [2015-01-20, 2015-01-15, 2015-01-17] then you want 2015-01-31)? Or do you want the latest *among your collection* (so with those three dates, you want 2015-01-20)? If you want 2015-01-31, then your question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python).

Comment: I want the chronologically last. Sure @Michael Laszlo ! let me just test it and I'll be sure to accept it. Thanks all !

Comment: You still didn't really answer my question, but it sounds like you want 2015-01-20, if given the list of three dates in my previous comment. Is that correct? Most people (including both of the answers below) have interpreted your question to mean you want 2015-01-31.

Comment: Yes I would like 2015-01-20. Thanks I'll edit the question to make it clearer !

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that only Michael Laszlo's answer had the mistaken interpretation; leroyJr seems to have read your question the way you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can handle this task really well.  Load your csv to a dataframe, then run a group by the month and find the max date using the aggregate function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file/')          # Load a dataframe with your file
df.index = df['my_date_field']              # set the dataframe index with your date
dfg = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))  # group by month / alternatively use MS for Month Start / referencing the previously created object

# Finally, find the max date in each month
dfg.agg({'my_date_field': np.max})

# To specifically coerce the results of the groupby to a list:
dfg.agg({'my_date_field': np.max})['my_date_field'].tolist()
```

Comment: still what I get is a `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1552CDF0>` , and I can't seem to access it as a normal list/array. like dfg[0]

Comment: Just one more step to change from the DataFrameGroupBy to a list:

    `dfg.agg({'a_date': np.max})['a_date'].tolist()  # Select the column and coerce`

Comment: If there's only a single column selected in your dataframe projection you issue a simpler aggregate command (just the function): `Dates.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).agg(np.max).tolist()`

Answer (score 4):

For year `y` and month `m`, `calendar.monthrange(y, m)[1]` returns the day number of the last day of the month.

The following script takes a list of `datetime` object called `dates` and makes a new list, `month_last_dates`, containing `datetime` objects corresponding to the last date of each month in which the members of `dates` fall.

```
import datetime
import calendar

tuples = [(2015, 8, 1), (2015, 9, 16), (2015, 10, 4)]
dates = [datetime.datetime(y, m, d) for y, m, d in tuples]

month_last_dates = len(dates) * [None]
for i, date in enumerate(dates):
  y, m, d = date.year, date.month, date.day
  last = calendar.monthrange(y, m)[1]
  print y, m, last  # Output for testing purposes.
  month_last_dates[i] = datetime.datetime(y, m, last)
```

Here is an equivalent script written more concisely with the help of a list comprehension:

```
import datetime
import calendar

tuples = [(2015, 8, 1), (2015, 9, 16), (2015, 10, 4)]
dates = [datetime.datetime(y, m, d) for y, m, d in tuples]

month_last_dates = [datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month,
      calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]) for date in dates]

# Output for testing purposes.
for date in month_last_dates:
  print date.year, date.month, date.day
```

In your case, given the list `Dates`, you can make a new list like this:

```
last_dates = [datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month,
      calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]) for date in Dates]
```

Comment: That is a good answer but the resulting list has the same size as the previous, ideally I'd like a list with the unique dates. Any ideas ? thanks !

Comment: Sure, you can do that to `last_dates`. Write: `last_dates = list(set(last_dates))` after the code I gave you above.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly, using just one line of code:

```
dates = [datetime.date(2023, 3, 21), datetime.date(2023, 3, 1), datetime.date(2023, 2, 22), datetime.date(2023, 2, 14)]
eom_dates = set(pd.Series(dates,index=dates).groupby(lambda x:x.month).max())
```

This results in:

```
{datetime.date(2023, 2, 22), datetime.date(2023, 3, 21)}
```