# how to get the first day and last day of current month in python

Tags: python

I am writing an SQL query to get the available data between the first date and last date of the current month in python. For this how can I get first and last date of current month.

Note: **In the question that already asked in stackoverflow only deals with end date. Also, I want the answer as a date field like 01-03-2016 or 31-03-2016.**

Comment: It could be helpful if you provide some example input with your expected output.

Comment: python solution was answered here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python)

Comment: Do you want your result to be in days of the week (Mo - Fr) or month (1 - 31)?

Comment: Also, do you want to get the date with python or with sql?

Comment: I would like to get the date in python like 01-03-2016 and 31-03-2016

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> how to get the first day and last day of current month in python

There's a function in the standard library [`calendar.monthrange(year, month)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange):

```py
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(2016, 3)
(1, 31)
```

**Careful**, `monthrange` **doesn't** return the dates of first and last days, but returns the weekday of the first day of the month, and number of days in month, for the specified year and month.

So to create first and last `date` objects, use **1** for the first day, and the number of days for the second day:

```py
>>> _, num_days = calendar.monthrange(2016, 3)
>>> first_day = datetime.date(2016, 3, 1)
>>> last_day = datetime.date(2016, 3, num_days)
>>> first_day
datetime.date(2016, 3, 1)
>>> last_day
datetime.date(2016, 3, 31)
```

Formatting these as strings:

```py
>>> first_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2016-03-01'
>>> last_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2016-03-31'
```

Comment: You can get the first date of the current month easily with `date.today().replace(day=1)`.

Comment: Yes, the more interesting use of `monthrange` is the last day

Comment: @bakkal  can i get the answer as like 01-03-2016 or 31-03-2016

Comment: @bakkal It was helpful. Thanks for your help