# Find the end of the month of a Pandas DataFrame Series

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I have a series within a DataFrame that I read in initially as an object, and then need to convert it to a date in the form of *yyyy-mm-dd* where *dd* is the end of the month.

As an example, I have DataFrame `df` with a column `Date` as an object:

```
...      Date    ...
...     200104   ...
...     200508   ...
```

What I want when this is all said and done is a date object:

```
...      Date    ...
...  2001-04-30  ...
...  2005-08-31  ...
```

such that `df['Date'].item()` returns

```
datetime.date(2001, 04, 30)
```

I've used the following code to get almost there, but all my dates are at the beginning of the month, not the end. Please advise.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m").dt.date
```

Note: I've already imported Pandas (pd), and datetime (dt)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m") + MonthEnd(0)
```

The `0` in `MonthEnd` just specifies to roll forward to the end of the given month. Note that if we'd used `MonthEnd(1)`, then we'd have got the next date which is at the end of the month.
If you wanted the last day of the next month, you'd then add an extra `MonthEnd(1)`, etc.  This should work for any month, so you don't need to know the number days in the month, or anything like that.  More offset information can be found in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics).

Example usage and output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [200104, 200508, 201002, 201602, 199912, 200611]})
df['EndOfMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m") + MonthEnd(1)

     Date EndOfMonth
0  200104 2001-04-30
1  200508 2005-08-31
2  201002 2010-02-28
3  201602 2016-02-29
4  199912 1999-12-31
5  200611 2006-11-30
```

Comment: This is by far one of the most elegant solutions I have ever seen, thank you! :)

Comment: No problem!  `MonthEnd` is one of the gems hidden in Pandas that you wouldn't immediately think Pandas would have.  Usually my first instinct is to use other datetime libraries..until I remember Pandas has such cool functionality!

Comment: you should check out @martien lubberink's answer for some caveats to the above.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for pandas 0.19.2 and numpy 1.13.1. Received error "data type datetime not understood". Anyone ran into this issue?

Comment: As explained in the [answer by Martein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43177530/), the use of `MonthEnd(1)` is incorrect for the last date of a month, and it should always just be `MonthEnd(0)` instead.

Comment: Can somebody please edit the answer? As mentioned above, we should use ```MonthEnd(0)``` instead of ```MonthEnd(1)```. This question is very common and having wrong answer as the one with the highest rating misleads people.

Comment: What's the difference between `MonthEnd(0)` and `MonthEnd(1)`. This answer suggests there **is** a difference but doesn't explain what it is.

Answer (score 95):

Agreed that root offers is the right method. However, readers who blindly use  `MonthEnd(1)` are in for a surprise if they use the last date of the month as an input:

```
In [4]: pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01') + MonthEnd(1)
Out[4]: Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00')

In [5]: pd.Timestamp('2014-01-31') + MonthEnd(1)
Out[5]: Timestamp('2014-02-28 00:00:00')
```

Using `MonthEnd(0)` instead gives this:

```
In [7]: pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01') + MonthEnd(0)
Out[7]: Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00')

In [8]: pd.Timestamp('2014-01-31') + MonthEnd(0)
Out[8]: Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00')
```

Example to obtain the month end as a string:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
(pd.Timestamp.now() + MonthEnd(0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00')
# '2014-01-31T00:00:00'
```

Comment: So what does the parameter passed to `MonthEnd` actually **do** ? It's clear from this that **0 should always be used as the parameter** but this raises questions such as what is the purpose of this parameter, and why would you ever want to pass `1` or any other non-zero value, as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

The end of the month can be the last day/minute/second/millisecond/microsecond/nanosecond of the month depending upon the [offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) needed by your use case. Given a date, to derive the last unit of the month, use the applicable [anchored offset semantics](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics). For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

def last_second_of_month(date: str) -> str:
    return str(pd.Timestamp(date) + pd.offsets.MonthBegin() - pd.offsets.Second())
```

As needed, replace `Second()` above with `Day()`, `Minute()`, `Milli()`, `Micro()`, or `Nano()`.

Here is an alternative implementation with the same result:

```py
import pandas as pd

def last_second_of_month(date: str) -> str:
    return str((pd.Timestamp(date) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)).date()) + " 23:59:59"
```

Examples:

```py
>>> last_second_of_month('2020-10')
'2020-10-31 23:59:59'
>>> last_second_of_month('2020-10-01')
'2020-10-31 23:59:59'
>>> last_second_of_month('2020-10-15')
'2020-10-31 23:59:59'
>>> last_second_of_month('2020-10-30')
'2020-10-31 23:59:59'
>>> last_second_of_month('2020-10-31')
'2020-10-31 23:59:59'
```

As a cautionary note, **do not use** `pd.Timestamp(date) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd() + pd.offsets.Day() - pd.offsets.Second()` as it doesn't work as required for the last date of a month. This observation about [`pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) is credited to the [answer by Martien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43177530/).