# Pandas: "data type datetime not understood" error in date offset operation

Tags: pandas, numpy, datetime

I am trying to do date shift just as the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354105/find-the-end-of-the-month-pandas-dataframe-series):

After pd.to_datetime(), the data type is datetime64[ns].

However I am receiving **"data type 'datetime' not understood"** error. The error comes from ops.py line 454:

```
     if (inferred_type in ('datetime64', 'datetime', 'date', 'time') or
            is_datetimetz(inferred_type)):
```

(Incidentally in debug mode, if I change to *('datetime64', 'a', 'b', 'c')* it doesn't throw the error)

I am using pandas version 0.19.2 and numpy 1.13.1.

Comment: You should provide some data so that we can reproduce the error and be able to help.

Comment: Please show your code and the full traceback