# Why is Column 'Date' getting replaced by last working day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-3.6

I am working with a data frame which has a date column and I have to find the last working date of every month, the code I used works but it doesn't make sense how it worked

The data frame 'apple' had 6 columns initially but I am mainly concerned with the 'Date' column which has dates ranging from the year 2014-1980 of every month
Sample Data:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close
0   2014-07-08  96.27   96.80   93.92   95.35   65130000    95.35
1   2014-07-07  94.14   95.99   94.10   95.97   56305400    95.97
2   2014-07-03  93.67   94.10   93.20   94.03   22891800    94.03
3   2014-07-02  93.87   94.06   93.09   93.48   28420900    93.48
4   2014-07-01  93.52   94.07   93.13   93.52   38170200    93.52
```

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
apple['Last_Day']=pd.to_datetime(apple['Date'],format="%Y-%m")+MonthEnd(0)
banana=apple.loc[-apple.Last_Day.duplicated()]
```

I expected the newly created 'Last_Day' column will have the last day of every month which I got but surprisingly the 'Date' column got the last working day of every month which I didn't understand cause I did not initialize anything to 'Date' so how did all the values in 'Date' get replaced by last working day,
Output:

```
    Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume    Adj Close  Last_Day
0   2014-07-08  96.27   96.80   93.92   95.35   65130000    95.35   2014-07-31
5   2014-06-30  92.10   93.73   92.09   92.93   49482300    92.93   2014-06-30
26  2014-05-30  637.98  644.17  628.90  633.00  141005200   90.43   2014-05-31
47  2014-04-30  592.64  599.43  589.80  590.09  114160200   83.83   2014-04-30
68  2014-03-31  539.23  540.81  535.93  536.74  42167300    76.25   2014-03-31
89  2014-02-28  529.08  532.75  522.12  526.24  92992200    74.76   2014-02-28
108 2014-01-31  495.18  501.53  493.55  500.60  116199300   70.69   2014-01-31
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data with expected output, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @jezrael added.

Comment: Line 0 was not replaces

Comment: Have you been using groupby? Can you provide full code?

Comment: @Arkady.A I did not use groupby. Initially the Date column was 'object' type, I changed that to datetime, otherwise nothing else done on original data.

Comment: @PrejithAlex Add more code and information for more clarity

Comment: @ShlomiBazel any idea why is it happening?

Comment: @Rahulcharan this is the whole code , ```apple``` dataframe was given and in that the only thing I did this before this was to convert ```Date``` from object type to datetime type. I cant understand why is the ```Date``` column getting replaced

Comment: @PrejithAlex I noticed some functions that are used return data which you must initialize in a new variable, and some other functions are making work on the current dataframe you provide. Try initializing a new variable `temp = df['Date']` and then perform the changes on it `pd.to_datetime(temp`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, my doubt is why is the Date column getting replaced by last working date, I do want the last working day but I did not understand how was the Date column replaced by last working day

There is no replacement, but last value of `Date` per month and year depends of data in `Date` column after removed duplicates.

So here is last value same like `Last_Day`, with exception July 2014 - there is last day of month `2014-07-08`.

For better understanding changed data and sorted - then get first value per month or last vlue oper month:

```
print (apple)
         Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close
0  2014-07-08  96.27  96.80  93.92  95.35  65130000      95.35
1  2014-06-07  94.14  95.99  94.10  95.97  56305400      95.97
2  2014-06-03  93.67  94.10  93.20  94.03  22891800      94.03
3  2014-05-31  93.87  94.06  93.09  93.48  28420900      93.48
4  2014-07-31  93.52  94.07  93.13  93.52  38170200      93.52

from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

apple['Date']=pd.to_datetime(apple['Date'])
apple = apple.sort_values('Date')
print (apple)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close
3 2014-05-31  93.87  94.06  93.09  93.48  28420900      93.48
2 2014-06-03  93.67  94.10  93.20  94.03  22891800      94.03
1 2014-06-07  94.14  95.99  94.10  95.97  56305400      95.97
0 2014-07-08  96.27  96.80  93.92  95.35  65130000      95.35
4 2014-07-31  93.52  94.07  93.13  93.52  38170200      93.52

apple['Last_Day']=apple['Date']+MonthEnd(0)
banana=apple.loc[-apple.Last_Day.duplicated()]
print (banana)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close   Last_Day
3 2014-05-31  93.87  94.06  93.09  93.48  28420900      93.48 2014-05-31
2 2014-06-03  93.67  94.10  93.20  94.03  22891800      94.03 2014-06-30
0 2014-07-08  96.27  96.80  93.92  95.35  65130000      95.35 2014-07-31
```

---

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd


apple['Date']=pd.to_datetime(apple['Date'])
apple1 = apple.sort_values('Date', ascending=False)
print (apple1)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close
4 2014-07-31  93.52  94.07  93.13  93.52  38170200      93.52
0 2014-07-08  96.27  96.80  93.92  95.35  65130000      95.35
1 2014-06-07  94.14  95.99  94.10  95.97  56305400      95.97
2 2014-06-03  93.67  94.10  93.20  94.03  22891800      94.03
3 2014-05-31  93.87  94.06  93.09  93.48  28420900      93.48

apple1['Last_Day']=apple1['Date']+MonthEnd(0)
banana1=apple1.loc[-apple1.Last_Day.duplicated()]
print (banana1)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close   Last_Day
4 2014-07-31  93.52  94.07  93.13  93.52  38170200      93.52 2014-07-31
1 2014-06-07  94.14  95.99  94.10  95.97  56305400      95.97 2014-06-30
3 2014-05-31  93.87  94.06  93.09  93.48  28420900      93.48 2014-05-31
```

Comment: I want the last working day which i was going to do in the subsequent step but my doubt is how did I get the Last working Day in the Date column when I didn't initialise Date, how did the original value in 'Date' get replaced by Last working day

Comment: @PrejithAlex - not understand, do you need replace `Date` column by last day of month?

Comment: No, my doubt is why is the ```Date``` column getting replaced by last working date, I do want the last working day but I did not understand how was the Date column replaced by last working day

Comment: @jezrael why are you giving `0 ` inside `Monthend`, could not find docstring/documentation

Comment: @pyd - replaced is `Last_Day` - it is last column, not `Date` - first column

Comment: @pyd check the accepted and the last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354105/find-the-end-of-the-month-pandas-dataframe-series) :)

Comment: ok @jezrael i want to know how the monthend works for `n=0` and `n=1`, pls send documentation link

Comment: @pyd - hmmm, I have to test it, here seems same (but maybe there are some differences, not sure)

Comment: yes, same here, n=0 and n=1 will give same result for some dates, I understood n=0 will give corresponding month's last working day, not sure about n=1 :(

Comment: @PrejithAlex - I try edit answer with sample data for better explanation, please check it.