# Selecting the last week of each month only from a data frame - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, group-by

If I have a data frame that is indexed by weekly dates (2019-01-07, 2019-01-14, 2019-01-21...etc), is there a way in Pandas to efficiently select only the rows that correspond to the last week of each month in the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354105/find-the-end-of-the-month-pandas-dataframe-series/43177530) last day of month (`MonthEnd`), then filter, for example (assuming that you have `Date` column in your `DataFrame`):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

df['MonthEnd'] = df['Date'] + MonthEnd(1)
df[ (df['MonthEnd'] - df['Date']).dt.days <= 7 ]
```

Comment: I believe it should it should be .dt.days instead of .days, but very helpful nonetheless - thank you!

Comment: @DalvirMandara you are welcome! Indeed it is, I wrote that code by memory :)