# Pandas Dataframe: Based a column of dates, create new column with last day of the month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Haven't found anything addressing this in a pandas dataframe.

So far I've tried this based on another stack overflow post but it is not working:

```
df['last_day_in_month'] = pd.Period(pd.to_datetime(df['date']),freq='M').end_time.date()
```

Pls excuse the quick picture but basically trying to replicate this in a pandas dataframe:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the end of the month of a Pandas DataFrame Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354105/find-the-end-of-the-month-of-a-pandas-dataframe-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['last_day_in_month'] = df['Date'] + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html) with the corresponding month frequency to get the month, then catch the last day with the "*end_time*" attribute:

```
df['date'].apply(lambda d: pd.Period(d, freq='M').end_time.date())
```

Then you can assign this value to your new column.