# python get day if its in a dates range

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to check if first date of the month and the last date of the month lies in a range of dates (the range is 7 days window starting from current date) . below is an example for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import datetime, calendar

today = datetime.date.today()
date_list = [today + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 7)]
lastDayOfMonth = today.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(today.year,today.month)[-1])
if 1 in [ date_list[i].day for i in range(0, len(date_list))]:
    print "we have first day of month in range"

elif lastDayOfMonth  in  [ date_list[i].day for i in range(0, len(date_list))]:
    print " we have last date of month in the range"
```

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way for doing that? I also want to print the exact date if I find it in the list but I don't know how without expanding the for loop in the if statement and save print `date_list[i]` if it matches my condition. so instead of printing the message when I find the first day in the range I should print the actual date. same for last date.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if I totally understand what you are trying to accomplish, but why not just grab the last day of the month and see if it's less than 6 days away? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python

Comment: `1 <= weekFromToday.day` this will only be True if "week from today" lies on the first day of the month.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you're right! I need to change that. Should I create a range then and check if day=1 lies in them? if so print it.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do, are you trying to see if the week does not extend into the next month? Or are you trying to, given another date, see if it is within a week from the current date?  If it is the second case use `today <= OTHER_DATE <= weekFromToday` and if the first case Tyler's suggestion would be the solution.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope its clearer now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can come up with, without having to make use of iteration is:

```
import datetime, calendar

today = datetime.date.today()
week_from_today = today + datetime.timedelta(days=6)
last_day_of_month = today.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(today.year,today.month)[-1])

if today.month != week_from_today.month:
    print datetime.date(week_from_today.year, week_from_today.month, 1)
elif today <= last_day_of_month <= week_from_today:
    print last_day_of_month
```

since today it's `2016-06-02` it's hard to test the code.
Try changing the variable `today` to another day. I used the dates `2016-05-25` and `2016-05-26` to test the code.

to set a custom date: `today = datetime.date(yyyy, m, d)`

Comment: you realize you can make a specific date with `datetime.date(year, month, day)` right?  That would be a significantly easier way to test...

Comment: also I don't think the iteration would be necessary for this, if the months are different then the wanted day would be `datetime.date(weekFromToday.year, weekFromToday.month, 1)`

Comment: @Do0msDay Thanks a lot!