# How to check dates basing on year and month in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to check the days for a given month . For an instance, if I input year 2017 and month 2 or February , I would like to receive all dates for that month, in this case 01-28.02.2017.

Is it possible to do in Python? Was trying to find something using google, but unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Day of the Month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python)

Comment: I am not looking for last day of month but for all days

Comment: Every month starts with day 1. If you know the first day and the last, then you also know everything between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function for this in the standard library: [`itermonthdates()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdates).

```
from calendar import Calendar

for date in Calendar().itermonthdates(2017, 2):
    print(date)
```

You may need to filter the dates with `if date.month == 2`, because it will contain days from the previous and next months if they belong to the same week.

Comment: Does this take leap years into account?

Comment: @mikey yes, it does.

Comment: so `for date in (d for d in Calendar().itermonthdates(2017, 2) if d.month == 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, as Mark suggested in the comments, if you know the month then you can do this yourself.

```
import calendar

year, month = 2017, 2

def days_in_month(date):
    if calendar.isleap(date.year) and date.month == 2:
        return 29
    else:
        return [None, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, ...][date.month]

date = datetime.date(year=year, month=month)

dates = [datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=d) for d in range(1, days_in_month(date)+1)]
```