# Create a last day of month indicator in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

How can I create an indicator for last day of the month?

Please help I've been struggling on this.

Input

```
Dates            Item        Sales           
2017-01-01       Apple       10
2017-01-02       Pear        10 
2017-01-31       Apple       10
2017-02-02       Apple       10
2017-01-28       Apple       10
```

Output

```
Dates            Item        Sales      Last day of month      
2017-01-01       Apple       10         No    
2017-01-02       Pear        10         No
2017-01-31       Apple       10         Yes
2017-02-02       Apple       10         No
2017-02-28       Apple       10         Yes
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Day of the Month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python)

Comment: Not really a dupe of that at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`dt.is_month_end`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.is_month_end.html):

```
df['Last day of month'] = np.where(df['Dates'].dt.is_month_end, 'Yes', 'No')
print (df)
       Dates   Item  Sales Last day of month
0 2017-01-01  Apple     10                No
1 2017-01-02   Pear     10                No
2 2017-01-31  Apple     10               Yes
3 2017-02-02  Apple     10                No
4 2017-02-28  Apple     10               Yes
```

Thanks, [Anton vBR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369490/create-a-last-day-of-month-indicator-in-python/47369509?noredirect=1#comment81691944_47369509) for solution inspired by [`Wen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369675/2901002):

```
df['Dates'].dt.is_month_end.map({1:'Yes',0:'No'})
```

Comment: Obviously the right choice if pd already has a function for it. +1. Inspired by @Wen I think: `df['Dates'].dt.is_month_end.map({1:'Yes',0:'No'})` is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

By using `pd.offsets`

```
df['Last day of month']=(df.Dates==df.Dates+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)).map({1:'Yes',0:'No'})
df
Out[275]: 
       Dates   Item  Sales Last day of month
0 2017-01-01  Apple     10                No
1 2017-01-02   Pear     10                No
2 2017-01-31  Apple     10               Yes
3 2017-02-02  Apple     10                No
4 2017-02-28  Apple     10               Yes
```

Comment: Nice, was about to post something very similar. I liked the map dict to convert True False.