# Return Last Day of Month for Range of Years - Python

Tags: python, date

I have some code that returns the last day of every month in 2017.

Results:

```
2017-01-31
2017-02-28
2017-03-31
2017-04-30
2017-05-31
2017-06-30
2017-07-31
2017-08-31
2017-09-30
2017-10-31
2017-11-30
2017-12-31
```

However, I would like to make it include the years 2014 through 2017 and not just 2017. I have not been able to find anything online that would accomplish this and have not been able to figure it out myself. All help/advice would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import calendar

#returns last day of each month
def lastdayofmonth(anyday):
    nextmonth = anyday.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=nextmonth.day)
for month in range(1, 13):
    print (lastdayofmonth(datetime.date(2017, month, 1)))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Day of the Month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `for` loop and loop through the years as you did with the months:

```
for year in range(2014,2018):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        print (lastdayofmonth(datetime.date(year, month, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
import calendar

{(k, m): calendar.monthrange(k, m)[1] for k in range(2014, 2018) for m in range(1, 13)}

# {(2014, 1): 31,
#  (2014, 2): 28,
#  (2014, 3): 31,
#  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

As *VIG* said, you can run second loop to iterator years as your expect range. BTW, I run your code got a error, said `next_month` no define. you code should fixed as below:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import calendar

#returns last day of each month
def lastdayofmonth(anyday):
    nextmonth = anyday.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    return nextmonth - datetime.timedelta(days=nextmonth.day)


for j in range(2014,2018):

    for month in range(1, 13):
        print (lastdayofmonth(datetime.date(j, month, 1)))
```