# How to get the EOMONTH(End of month) of the current date using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a SQL server stored procedure and I am trying to replicate it using python. One of the things I am trying to replicate is the following function:

```
DECLARE @Anchor_DT as DATE =EOMONTH(Getdate(),-1);
```

Here is what I have tried in Python3:

```
import datetime
datetime.date (2000, 3, 1) - datetime.timedelta (days = 1)
```

Output:

```
datetime.date(2000, 2, 29)
```

The thing is, I have to enter the date (200,3,1). I want to be able to pick up the current date and output the End of month. Here is what I tried but to no avail:

```
import datetime
datetime.date.now() - datetime.timedelta (days = 1)
```

Any suggestions or recommended solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Day of the Month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today()
print(datetime.datetime((now.year + (now.month // 12)), (now.month + 1) % 12, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days = 1))
```

Or, you could use the [calendar.monthrange](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) method:

```
import calendar
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today()
_, lastday = calendar.monthrange(now.year, now.month)
print(datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, lastday))
```

Comment: For those looking at this later like I was, one warning: The top snippet does not work when today is in December. It results in month = 13, which gives the following error:

`ValueError: month must be in 1..12`

The second snippet should work, or you can add logic to round the number back to one if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
adate = datetime.datetime(2023,2,1)     # an arbitrary date
eomdate = adate+ relativedelta(day = 31)  # EOM for the arbitrary date.
```