# What is the python 3 version of this answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, typeerror

I found an answer to getting the last day of months: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13565185/11661097

This answer is in python 2 and in python 3 when I run this code I get this error:

```
print(self.last_day_of_month(start))
TypeError: last_day_of_month() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

start is a datetime object (datetime.date(someyear, somemonth, someday) so it should be exactly the same as the answer given in the question.

Is this because the answer is in python 2? If so, how would I rewrite it so it works in python 3?

Comment: The only difference between Python 2 and 3 relevant here is that 3 requires parentheses to call the `print` function.

Comment: you made a method but forgot `self` as a parameter or `@staticmethod` as a decorator

Comment: @AnthonySottile Yea I realized that and was about to delete this question haha but thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `last_day_of_month()`

- Use `self` as the first parameter, and
- Use `start` as the second parameter,

So, do `last_day_of_month(self, start)`