# Python Dataframe Date plus months variable which comes from the other column

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, relativedelta

[image]

I have a dataframe with the date and month_diff variable. I would like to get a new date (name it as Target_Date) based on the following logic:
For example, the date is 2/13/2019, month_diff is 3, then the target date should be the month-end of the original date plus 3 months, which is 5/31/2019

I tried the following method to get the traget date first:

```
df["Target_Date"] = df["Date"] + pd.DateOffset(months = df["month_diff"])
```

But it failed, as I know, the parameter in the dateoffset should be a varaible or a fixed number.

I also tried:

```
df["Target_Date"] = df["Date"] + relativedelta(months = df["month_diff"])
```

It failes too.

Anyone can help? thank you.

edit:
this is a large dataset with millions rows.

Comment: `relativedelta` does not work on series like that. try: `df.apply(lambda row: row.Date + relativedelta(months = row.month_diff)`. Maybe change the axis or something. This won't be too efficient if the data is too large though.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the end_date or the month_diff?

Comment: @bramb   I am trying to retrieve the `Target_Date` which highlighted in the table.

Comment: Okay, have you tried my part below?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [pd.datetime(2019,1,1), pd.datetime(2019,2,1)], 'month_diff': [1,2]})
df.apply(lambda row: row.Date + relativedelta(months=row.month_diff), axis=1)
```

Or list comprehension

```
[date + relativedelta(months=month_diff) for date, month_diff in df[['Date', 'month_diff']].values]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach in the following method to compute your "target_date".

1. Apply the target month offset (in your case +3months), using your pd.DateOffset.
2. Get the last day of that target month (using for example calendar.monthrange, see also "[Get last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month)").  This will provide you with the "flexible" part of that date" offset.
3. Apply the flexible day offset, when comparing the result of step 1. and step 2.  This could be a new pd.DateOffset.

A solution could look something like this:

```py
import calendar
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

for ii in df.index:
    new_ = df.at[ii, 'start_date'] + relativedelta(months=df.at[ii, 'month_diff'])
    max_date = calendar.monthrange(new_.year, new_.month)[1]
    end_ = new_ + relativedelta(days=max_date - new_.day)
    print(end_)
```

Further "cleaning" into a function and / or list comprehension will probably make it much faster

Comment: thanks, bramb.  This solution use `for ii in df.index`, this is kind of loop, I assume it is time-consuming for the large dataset. right?

Comment: You can alter it to a list comprehension or to a function.  It would make it more efficient ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
```

This is my approach in solving your issue.
However for some reason I am getting a semantic error in my output even though I am sure it is the correct way. Please everyone correct me if you notice something wrong.

```
today = datetime.now()
today = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
month_diff =[30,5,7]
n = 30
for i in month_diff:
    b = {'Date': today, 'month_diff':month_diff,"Target_Date": datetime.now()+timedelta(days=i*n)}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=b)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

For some reason the **i** is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution I can write in one line only and `apply` does the job. However, by default `apply` function performs action on each column, so you have to remember to specify correct axis: `axis=1`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Create a new column with date adjusted by number of months from 'month_diff' column and later adjust to the last day of month
df['Target_Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Date # to current date
        + relativedelta(months=row.month_diff)    # add month_diff
        + relativedelta(day=+31)                  # and adjust to the last day of month
        , axis=1)                                 # 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.
```