# python:add month date to the column by 10 months

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataset with a START_DATE column and a string column like this:

```
START_DATE             string
2017-03-31                a
2017-04-30                b
2017-05-30                c
```

I want to transform it into this format like this:

```
START_DATE             string
2017-03-31                a
2017-04-30                b
2017-05-30                c 
2017-06-30
2017-07-31
2017-08-31
2017-09-30
2017-10-31
2017-11-30
2017-12-31
2017-01-31
2017-02-28
2017-03-31
```

Is there any easy solution to this question?

Thanks!

Comment: What question? Why till the 8th month?

Comment: hi,@yatu, it is a sample.It shows that i just want to add some date into START_DATE by monthly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for how long this should go on, but you could use a for loop that spans over a certain time window, adding one month to the current date at every iteration and get the last day of the month.

In order to get the last day of the month, see [Get last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month)