# How to handle date error with months in datetime.replace in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have the date object which is as follows. Date: `2025-11-30`. If I add 3 month to it using following code, it will raise an Exception as follows.

code:

```
def get_next_n_month_forward(date, n):
    if date.month + n > 12:
        next_month = date.replace(year=date.year + 1,
                                  month=(date.month + n) % 12)
    else:
        next_month = date.replace(month=(date.month + n))
    return next_month
```

exception:

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

As far as I can understand from error it is because february does not have 30th day.

**Question:** How can I make it set to the last day of the month? !Note: In my case it would be 29th or 28th of February.

Comment: using calendar module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month

Comment: why not use relativedelta?

Comment: So what is result for 2020-01-31 + 1month ? what do you expectd ? Same day x month later, x*30 days later ?

Comment: did not really get about that, can you try anything I would take an example from your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object to increase and decrease dates

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.today()
new_d = d + timedelta(days=1)
```

In order to set the date to the last day of month, you can set the date to the 1st of the next month and then decrease it by 1 day:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
day = datetime.datetime.today()
prev_month_last_day = day.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
```