# How to get the date range of the previous month?

Tags: python

I am attempting to get the date range of the previous month using Python. For example, today is January 4th, 2021 - I am looking for a way to retrieve "2020-12-01" and "2020-12-31".

I have started with the following:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

This gives me the previous month, which I can format like so:

```
beginningOfMonth = lastMonth.strftime("%Y-%m-01")
```

However, my attempts to use the `calendar` module to determine the end of the month/how many days are in the month have failed. Is there an easier way to do this? Preferably without too many package deps...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried https://www.google.com/search?q=get+length+of+given+month+python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 1):

Use `calendar.monthrange`:

```
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()

month = today.month
year = today.year

year = year if today.month != 1 else year - 1 # In case you switch year (Jan -> Dec)

last_month_day = monthrange(year, month)[1] # Number of days of the last month.
```

With this, you can reformat your strings, since every month starts at 1, and ends at `last_month_day`

Comment: If print last statement - `print(monthrange(year, month))`  it will give (2, 31)?  What does it mean then?  (never mind, i got it)  But Maybe you would like to reformat it?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. Now is corrected.