# How would I get the number of days in a month with numpy datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What is the easiest and most pythonic way to get the number of days in a month given a np.datetime64 value.

For example: `'2020-01-31T00:00:00.000000000' = 31`

I'm trying to find something equivalent to [Pandas.daysinmonth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.days_in_month.html), but for numpy.

```
#pd.daysinmonth example:
p = pd.Period('2018-2-17')
p.days_in_month
28
```

Comment: Just trying to use Numpy to improve speed/efficiency of code. Could you give me an example of how using pandas datetime could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` functions on `np.datetime64` objects:

```
>>> ts = np.datetime64('2020-01-31T00:00:00.000000000')
>>> ts
numpy.datetime64('2020-01-31T00:00:00.000000000')
>>> pd.Period(ts, freq='D').days_in_month
31
```

Or, using `np.datetime_as_string`:

```
>>> pd.Period(np.datetime_as_string(ts)).days_in_month
31
```

---

Here's a pure `numpy` solution, although I'm mildly positive there exists a better one.

```
>>> ts = np.datetime64('2020-01-31T00:00:00.000000000')
>>> def days_in_month(ts):
        ts_month = ts.astype('datetime64[M]')
        return (
            ((ts_month+1).astype('datetime64[D]') - ts_month) 
            // np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
         )
>>> days_in_month(ts)
31
```

It is vectorized and reasonably fast:

```
>>> arr = np.arange('2000-01', '2021-12', dtype='datetime64[D]')

>>> arr.shape
(8005,)

>>> %timeit days_in_month(arr)
586 µs ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```