# How to find the End Date of the month and convert the date format using Python

Tags: python, pandas

having a column where Month and year is given, Using Month and year need to find the Last date of the month, and hence convert the date format.

Where need to update StartDay using Date1 and EndDay using Date2.

**Input Data**

```
Date1     Date2    StartDay      EndDay

Apr2020  Dec2020  
Nov2020  Feb2021
Sep2018  Oct2020
Jan2020  Nov2020
Mar2018  Sep2020
```

**Expected Output**

```
Date1     Date2     StartDay         EndDay

Apr2020  Dec2020    2020-04-01       2020-12-31
Nov2020  Feb2021    2020-11-01       2021-12-28
Sep2018  Oct2020    2018-09-01       2020-10-31
Jan2020  Nov2020    2020-01-01       2020-11-30
Mar2018  Sep2020    2018-03-01       2020-09-30
```

Code been using So Far:

```
df['month'] = df.Date2.str[:3]
df['year'] = df.Date2.str[3:7]

df['Date1'] = df.Date1.str[:3] + '-' + df.Date1.str[3:]
df['col'] = '01-' + df['Date1'].astype(str)
df['StartDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDay'], errors='coerce')
df['StartDay'] = df['StartDay'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

How to find the End Date using the column Date2, Please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: @NicholasHunter - Thanks, But how to use it with the type of data i have , Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%b%Y` for match months first 3 letters with years in `YYYY`, so then only need to add [`pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html):

```
df['StartDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'], errors='coerce', format='%b%Y')
df['EndDay'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'], errors='coerce', format='%b%Y') + 
                pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1))
print (df)
     Date1    Date2   StartDay     EndDay
0  Apr2020  Dec2020 2020-04-01 2020-12-31
1  Nov2020  Feb2021 2020-11-01 2021-02-28
2  Sep2018  Oct2020 2018-09-01 2020-10-31
3  Jan2020  Nov2020 2020-01-01 2020-11-30
4  Mar2018  Sep2020 2018-03-01 2020-09-30
```