# How do convert from MMM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD, setting DD to the last day of month in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, date-conversion

I have a similar question on date conversion using data frame.

My data frame has two date string columns, `hiredate` and `end_date`, having different date formats, `DD-MMM-YYYY`and `MMM-YY`, respectively.

The column `end_date` has no `DD` to represent the day, so it should be added and set to the last day of the month.

Below is an example of the input data frame:

```py
 empno  ename    hiredate end_date
     1 sreenu 17-Jun-2021   May-22
```

And this is the expected output after `end_date` conversion:

```py
 empno  ename    hiredate   end_date
     1 sreenu 17-Jun-2021 2022-05-31
```

I want to create a method/function to identify all date columns in
the data frame and then convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried? And please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month to get the last day of the month in Python.

Comment: @rajah9, I tried this one before i posted. but above question is different than mine. I want create a method to convert DD-MM-YYYY and MMM-YY to YYYY-MM-DD format dynamically on my dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert `end_date` to datetime according to the format `'%B-%y'` and add a `MonthEnd(0)` offset:

Input data:

```py
>>> df
   empno   ename     hiredate end_date
0      1  sreenu  17-Jun-2021   May-22
```

Column transformation:

```py
>>> df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['end_date'], format='%b-%y'
).add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0))
```

Output result:

```py
>>> df
   empno   ename     hiredate   end_date
0      1  sreenu  17-Jun-2021 2022-05-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution pointed out in the comment -

```
pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], format='%b-%y').apply(lambda x: date(x.year, x.month, calendar.monthrange(x.year, x.month)[-1]))
```