# How can I select the last day of the month in a date column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called "date" that has data for every day of the year and I want to get only the row that corresponds to the last day of the month, how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: You don't say so, but I assume you're using Pandas? If so, you should [edit] your question to add the pandas tag - although the answer linked above should solve your problem.

Comment: I have a column called "date" that has data for every day of the year. I want to select only the row that corresponds to the last day of each month. Somebody can tell me how can I do that, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using pandas, you can use the [datetime package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to check this.

Since some months have differents amounts of days, I'm using it to check the date of the next day, if the next date have a day equal to 1, then the day we are at is the last of that month.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas

def check_last_month_day(day):
    next_day = date.fromisoformat(day) + timedelta(days=1)
    return next_day.day == 1
```

That function receives a string in the date format, creates an date object from that string and then adds one day in the date. After doing this, it just returns a boolean that checks if the day of the next date is equal to 1. for example:

```
>>> check_last_month_day('2020-01-30')
False
>>> check_last_month_day('2020-01-31')
True
```

So, now you can filter the dataframe rows using this function:
(assuming you named your dataframe as df)

```
df_filtered = df[ df['date'].apply(check_last_month_day) ]
```