# How to find last day of month in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

Do you know any Keyword or any Logic in Robot Framework to get the last day of the Each month.
Actually, I am working on a Calendar and in that Whenever it will be last day of the month I need to click on Next Button.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can build  a keyword around the answers here: [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 1):

Python's `calendar` library can provide this information.

In your Robot test script you can call
`calendar.monthrange(year, date)`
which will return a list of two numbers, the 0th element is the weekday of the first day of the month, and the 1st element is the days in the month.

In example

```
${year}=    Set Variable    2022
${month}=    Set Variable    2   
${tupleContainingEndDate}=    Evaluate    calendar.monthrange(${year}, ${month})
${numberOfDays}=    Set Variable    ${tupleContainingEndDate}[1]
Log    ${numberOfDays}
```

${numberOfDays} is:
`28`